# How are flag limits calculated?

Tags: discussion, flags, privileges

How are the daily flag limits calculated for each user?  I joined the site ~30 days ago and I think I had around 10 flags/day allowed.  Today, I just flagged a question and noticed that I had some 20 flags remaining.

[image: Woohoo!]

It probably has to do with rep, or past successful flags, but I'm interested in how exactly this is calculated, as it seems to have risen (albeit not linearly) over time.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149670/172958

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As per [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

You start off with 10 flags per day.
You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).
And there's a 100 flags per day cap you cannot exceed.

Comment: Is there many/any who would use the 100 flags in one day?

Comment: @Howlin I think the answer would be yes. I have just over 60 per day available to me right now, and if I spend almost an entire day on SO I can sometimes burn through 40-50 or so. A more veteran user who's more skilled at determining whether borderline posts need flagging or not might potentially, on a day full of off-topic questions, burn through even more. Looking at the [userlist sorted by reputation](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-04-01?sort=totalreputation), there are currently 1700 users with rep over 25k, so 1-2k people might need all 100 flags on occasion.

Comment: @Howlin, during elections you'll find a bunch of people who often use all their flags every day. The ones who do this well are often elected as moderators.

Comment: One aspect that is not clear from the help page: The limit applies to both posts and comments, but they are counted separately. So if your flag limit is 100, you can flag 100 posts and 100 comments, which adds up to a maximum of 200 flags per day. At least it looks that way empirically. I used 14 post flags today, and I'm shown 86 flags left when I click the link to flag a post, and 100 flags left for comments.

Comment: *You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).*
Does that bonus flag vanish when I use it, or it changes my limit forever?

Comment: @styrofoamfly the bonus is applied to your limit, no just one. E.g., let's assume you've just joined SO so only have 1 rep and 10 flags per day. Now you go around and correctly flag 10 spam posts. Your new limit will be 11 flags per day.

Comment: @Mureinik you need 15 rep to flag