# Should I review if I have no available flags?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, privileges

In my participation to SO I recently focused more on participating in the review process.

When reviewing questions from new users and late answers, I came across a lot of off-topic / homework / poor quality contributions which I flagged as such.
I do believe my flags are useful as my flag history doesn't include any single rejected flag (4 waiting for review, 26  deemed helpful, 6 disputed).

As I don't have enough reputation I can't vote to close and have to go through this longer process of flagging. This process is however limited to a certain amount of flags each day.

I came to the point of getting review which clearly needed to be either put on hold or closed. The only thing I was able to do was to downvote and comment, as I don't think skipping would be the good thing to do. But that doesn't change the fact that someone else will have to do the flagging/voting-to-close job I could have done.

My questions are:

- Should I participate to the reviewing process if I don't have any available flags?
- Is voting down and commenting enough?
- Should I focus on getting more reputation to earn the vote-to-close privilege (I'm only at 800/3000)?

Also:

- Rather then getting privileges from reputation, shouldn't privileges like vote-to-close be awarded based on the contribution to raising useful flags / participating in the review process?

Comment: If I have no flags left, I wouldn't review (personally). Also, the more helpful flags you get, the more available flags you will have every day. Having the vote to close privilege does not really give you very much beyond what you have now, as flagging things sends them into the close queue, where people will act on them (usually) no matter if it was sent there with a flag or a close vote. How you vote is up to you, and commenting is always a good idea for educating people on what they can ask and how to ask.

Comment: There are occasional suggestions to award privileges based on helpful flagging (the Marshal badge is often suggested as a benchmark), but they have not gone anywhere.

Comment: Where do you see these flags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should you stop reviewing when you run out of flags? Not necessarily... unless you want to stop, of course. Put it this way: how many of your reviews do result in a flag being raised? 10% of them? 25%? 50%? Even then, you still could handle the remaining 50% of the posts being reviewed - the ones where you select "No action needed", or you improve the post and move on, or you downvote and leave a comment.

However, I would advise against "just downvoting and commenting" a post which, in your opinion, should be closed or deleted. If you find one of these and you don't have any available flags left, I think it'd be better to <kbd>Skip</kbd> it, and let somebody else review it. There is nothing wrong with using the skip button!

On a side note, the system actually [raises your daily flag limit over time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251621/how-are-flag-limits-calculated), if it thinks you're using them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes sense to review when you haven't got any flags.

Half the point of the review process is to highlight questions that are not up to standard. I know that you could edit or downvote the questions but if you are limited by what you can do then you aren't doing the best job of it.

If you just downvote a question that needs to be flagged then that could be missed and remain on the site when it should be closed.

If you just skip all of the questions that need to be flagged then it just seems like wasting time reviewing.

It would be best to wait until you have flags available.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer... "trust the system". I guess it's pointless to fight it, and it's much easier to just stop trying.