# Reviewing without flags is almost pointless

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

A lot of times I use all my flags (15 per day) in the first round of reviewing but I wanted to continue reviewing other questions and answers.

At this point and for example in the "First Post" review I see a spam post but I can't do anything with it and I think just down voting wouldn't be enough.

And in the "Late answers" you cannot mark answers as something like "Not an answer" flag.

So I think reviewing without flags is pointless.

Should I stop reviewing at this point? Should I flag more carefully to save the flags!?

Comment: if you see a _spam_ post in first post queue, you can always click on the link at the right to go to the actual post and flag it..

Comment: there is no difference between flagging in the review queue and question it self. and sometimes its just a test :)

Comment: @M.R.Safari If it's an audit, downvoting will be enough to pass it. But if it's not an audit, there's not much you can do, but don't worry, if it's spam, others will flag it and it will be deleted quickly anyway.

Comment: If you flag more, and they're marked helpful, you'll get more daily flags (1 extra for each 10 helpful flags).

Comment: This seems like a design flaw.

Comment: You can always skip the things that need to be flagged once you run out.  Even if it's obviously bad or an audit, you'll never get penalized for skipping.

Comment: Guys! I'm not here looking for a solution really. I'm just saying this.I know I can skip the review and other stuff. I'm just saying that this is happening and its not good !

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**Don't save your flags!**

As Glorfindel mentioned in comments, the key to being able to flag, is to flag. For every ten helpful flags, you will get another daily flag, up to [100 a day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251621/how-are-flag-limits-calculated). If you use all of your flags everyday (and they are helpful), it does not take very long to get enough flags that it can be hard to use them all.

Answer (score 3):

There is certainly no reason to stop reviewing once you have used all your flags. The percentage of posts that I review that deserve to be flagged is quite low.

If you come across a post in a review queue that should be flagged when you have no flags left you can always add a comment that explains why the flag is appropriate and then skip the review. Someone else who has not run out of flags can then flag the post, and you can continue reviewing other posts that might just need an up or down vote or an edit.

Comment: "The percentage of posts that I review that deserve to be flagged is quite low." This is likely because you have close vote privileges, something the OP does not have.

Comment: @jpmc26 My point is that only a small percentage of the posts on the review queue deserve to be flagged (or close voted), so not being able to flag (or vote to close) is not a reason to avoid reviewing.

Comment: "My point is that only a small percentage of the posts on the review queue deserve to be flagged (or close voted)" You and I likely have different standards for what constitutes a good question if you think most posts don't deserve to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that you are a low enough reputation user that you cannot cast close votes, so you must flag when most reviewers would close. This means your flags are used up much more quickly than they would be for higher reputation users.

As such, I believe SO is trying to quietly game the system to encourage you to limit your reviewing activities. Lower reputation users are considered "less trusted." (Whether this is realistic is a completely different issue, but that is the view SO takes in its design.) When you can't cast close votes, your number of reviews per day is effectively limited by your number of flags. So this encourages you to not spend a large amount of time on reviews each day. Do also note that there are limits on close votes as well, but the limits are higher than the starting number of flags you have. Users also limit their reviewing activities themselves to avoid wearing themselves out and reviewing wrongly.

So my advice would be to stop reviewing once you run out of flags for now. You'll be able to review more extensively once you hit 3,000 reputation and can cast close votes. To raise your reputation, ask questions when you have good ones, and offer answers when you have good ones. And be patient. =) You'll hit 3,000 just fine, even if it takes some time.