# Decreased numbers of flags remaining

Tags: support, flags

I used to have 50 flags remaining at most on main site, now I have less than 35.

What happened? Did I do something wrong?
Could I be notified if so?

In my flag history, this is the status:

[image]

Comment: What does your flag history tell you?

Comment: @rene added a screenshot

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251621/how-are-flag-limits-calculated)?

Comment: I'm not sure you can get to > 50 available flags, considering your flag history. It should be, as you say, less than 35. 10 (initial) + 2 (rep bonus) + 19 (flag bonus) = 31.

Comment: It seems you might be confusing the number of *close votes* you have daily vs the number of flags you have... You can't have reached 50 flags yet given your rep and helpful flag count (see the post @yivi has linked you to...)

Comment: indeed, I confused them - thanks for the help