# Where do I find my daily flag limit?

Tags: support, flags

I know I can see my remaining flags when attempting to flag and also how they are [calculated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251621/13629335). But where do I find in the middle of the day, without the need of a calculator, the limit of flags I currently have? Because in my *flag summary* I could not find it.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBQvS.png), but requires that you haven't flagged that day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are flag limits calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251621/how-are-flag-limits-calculated)

Comment: Why you can't wait to the next day? What is really missing in referred help article?

Comment: @Rubén I could. But I thought, while this number is generated it could be found somewhere without a calculator or an alarm reminding me to look it up before using any flags. So the answer to my question is nowhere ?

Comment: Have you read the help article about flags?

Comment: @Rubén I have read https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts. Did you mean that ? because there they state how I calculate them. Could you please focus on my question ?

Comment: @Rubén What exactly is in that article you think addresses the OP question? Because I'm not seeing it. Unless your point is "OP doing it wrong, just jump the hoops like everyone else"?

Comment: The short answer to your exact question, as my comment should've been more explicit about, is that you don't. It isn't listed anywhere. You can only see it in the flag dialog when you haven't flagged yet

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine So no missing hint in the help center, just an incomplete summary. You could post it as answer, so I can close this question with an answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Perhaps this should be turned into a [feature-request]? The text on the dialog could say something like "Flags left for today: 9 of 20", for example. That would be nice to have. It would also help you quickly check how many flags you've already _spent_ today.

Comment: If you can / are allowed to run userscripts maybe one of [these](https://stackapps.com/search?q=%5Bscript%5D+%5Bflags%5D+is%3Aq) provide the info you're looking for.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I posted a FR about this on MSE: [Include the daily flag limit in the flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382947/348196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it appears that you need to calculate you can do it with less calculation than  the [help center suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). Flags are reset, as everything on a daily basis, at 0 UTC. You could take the [actual UTC time](https://time.is/en/UTC) and then just add the flags you have used today after 0 UTC to the [remaining flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBQvS.png) you have left. This could still require to count up to 100 but if you remind yourself and just have used 5 of them, you are in luck.