# Can I block/hide activity of a user?

Tags: support

This doesn't really apply to Stack Overflow, more to Meta where posts are opinionated.

Is there any way I can block/hide activity of a user on Meta? Questions, Answers & Comments. Not because of any dislike for certain users, but mainly I find their posts to be nonsensical, repetitive, walls of textual noise and they really get in my way of enjoying all the good content and opinions here on Meta.

Something like what happens when an answer gets downvoted where the text is set to light grey. I don't want to post a screenshot just in case I cause any offence!

Even a userscript or something would suffice if someone has one.

Comment: Nope, you can't. (Well, without a userscript)

Comment: You can flag them and we can hide them for you.

Comment: @BoltClock: I just flagged your post. Why isn't it gone yet?!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I hid your flag.

Comment: @BoltClock I would run out of flags...seriously :) Also, they're not even really *flaggable* - just noise.

Comment: @BoltClock: ooh, OHH! That is just *mean*!

Comment: @BoltClock Who are you talking to? Ah wait ... never mind.

Comment: I really want this as well, there are a **few** users here that really is just trolling in away they can't get flagged. I got in particular one user I don't really want to see neither comments,answers or questions from. Generally I'm considering just leaving all together, and revert to using academic sources. Fortunately more academic "sub sites" aren't "pestered", as  you need some education to understand what people are discussing. (No offence intended to those who don't have any formal degree)

Comment: Right, I found one annoying uneducated commenter being stubborn for a wrong point which never intended to answer the question in the first place. I saw his profile and he never asks any question, only answer regex question or gain points from editing. It proves a high point in StackOverflow doesn't mean you are a real legit programmer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been requested as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) before: [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

The request was, of course, [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), and I expect that to continue to be true. There are a few good reasons *not* to implement this in Stack Exchange in answers from people with diamonds.

However, someone has created a user script, details of which are here: [Ignore Users Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script)
It's provided with the following caveat:

> This script is not meant to be a solution for bad behavior on Stackoverflow [sic]. If you feel somebody is violating the rules of this site, please contact the proper authorities (team@stackoverflow.com).

I make no representation whether it still works or not.

Comment: While the reasons on that post do not correlate to my own, nor the way that meta works, that looks like an acceptable solution so thanks!

Comment: What are these "good reasons" you talk about? I can't seem to find them anywhere.

Comment: @TLP One good reason is that if you don't see all the answers/comments you can provide an answer, which adds no value to already existing answer(s)/comment(s). The other reason is that if you ask question and ignored user provided briliant answer, then you don't see this answer, and intercommunication among community is harmed.

Comment: @doc I would expect that answers are exempt from the blocking, as they can be downvoted and edited by other users, and therefore not so prone to contain attacks on other users.

Comment: To be honest, I will trade a few points just to block some people. I think that solves everything. If you want to be comfortable, contribute more and you may have it

Comment: A bit old this post, but didn't want to start a new one along similar lines (so many have been downvoted).   I don't want to block users - but can we at least have the ability to create a personal list of users that we'd rather not answer their questions.  Just have the user name appear in another colour or something.