# What does +0 bounty earned stand for?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) user has earned a +0 bounty for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983915/is-time-a-good-salt) answer.

How did this happen? And why there is no bounty icon next to his answer?

Comment: Note that, five months after the events described above happened, [the system was changed to prevent this](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/54998/271976#97802 "I just awarded myself a bounty"). A subsequent [request to restore the capability](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/166172/271976 "Explicit “do not award bounty” button") was denied.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It was their own bounty, and by awarding it to their own answer the bounty is set to 0. You can never 'earn back' a bounty you placed this way.

See the [question revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4983915/revisions):

> **Bounty Started** worth **100** reputation by [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)
>
> **Bounty Ended** with **[Your Common Sense's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983915/is-time-a-good-salt/4984180#4984180)** chosen by [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)

and the [answer revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4984180/revisions):

> **Bounty Ended** with **0** reputation awarded by [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)

There is little point in showing a `+0` bounty indicator next to the post in this case.

Comment: Hmm, reminds me of a war story.  A company I worked for had a tough competitor who named their product "Compact".  It was a very good product, the only quality it lacked was compactness.

Answer (score 14):

The person offering the bounty decided it award it to his / her answer. This results in the behavior that you have reported. Even though the bounty was awarded but reps cannot be earned via this approach.

This is also evident from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4983915/revisions) message:

> Bounty Ended with Your Common Sense's answer chosen by Your Common Sense