# Should I downvote attempted answers to bad (too broad) questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Broad questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266893/create-one-page-responsive-website-using-bootstrap-css3-and-html5) (now deleted):

> I have to make one website like
>
> http://preview.effekthemes.com/focus
>
> using HTML5,CSS3,jQuery and bootstrap
>
> so please suggest me from where I have to start? which is better and
>   easy way to do this?
>
> I dont have knowledge of either three(html5,css3,boostrap).
>
> Please help me.
>
> 1)How to make responsive html as in above example?
>
> 2)how to create section with fix image in that? and also how to set
>   image slider in that?

...invite well meant attempts to answer their parts, but none really answers the question.

Is it OK to downvote them and post a comment like this?

> -1 You shouldn't try to answer too broad questions, but flag them as being such.

It might enforce the idea that SO can be very harsh to newbies.

Comment: I find it ironic that you have an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23269296/1906307) on the very question you are presenting as example.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an answer.

Comment: It should be flagged for not being an answer, but a comment that wanted nicer markup.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm convinced that if I flagged that as NAA, it would be declined.

Comment: ^^^ Sure.  downvote away.

Comment: @Will great find... I still need to get adjusted to the meta split. I just searched here...

Comment: You want harsh go read the post about why SO is so negative as of late.

Comment: Wow we really have had a number of questions in the last 24-36 hours it seems on what should happen to answerers on bad questions of one form or another.  Seems to be a trend.

Comment: @demongolem not a trend, but a way of life. ObTopic: SO isn't harsh to newbies, it's harsh to people that jump in to a new community without bothering to explore how that community operates, even to the extent of ignoring warnings and guidance that the site provides.

Comment: how can this question be off-topic? seriously?

Comment: You can downvote the question itself you know :o

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It isn't off-topic, as it clearly *is* about Stack Overflow. But you can't flag it as a dupe for a question on another meta site.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: even if it's the main meta? that doesn't make sense. maybe this question should be moved there? saying that the current resolution is confusing is an understatement....

Comment: I think moving it there, will just end up in having it duped here again in the future.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: so there's no way to properly resolve it? Clearly there's something wrong with the system.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you would enjoy this "question" http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251375/meta-hasnt-changed-at-all

Comment: @DoubleDouble: thank you! unfortunately I can hardly enjoy the answers.

Comment: surely a good answer to any question improves the quality of this resource we work towards? I say vote an answer on its merits, and vote a question on its merits. But do not vote an answer on the merits of the question. You wouldn't vote a question on the merits of the answers provided, would you?

Comment: I think it's legitimate to post an answer that only answers part of a question.  Such a post should not be a comment, since it isn't a request for clarification or a recommendation on rephrasing the question, and it does provide information that may be useful, even highly useful.

Comment: >"It might enforce the idea that SO can be very harsh to newbies." -Why the heck would I want to do that? The Usenet was in the nineties. The September That Never Ended was the best darn thing that ever happened to The Internet, despite the hand-wringing otherwise. Positive reinforcement ALWAYS works better than negative. It's called an "R+" methodology (Performance Management, by Daniels & Daniels).

Comment: @MAGSHARE What the heck makes you think I would?

Comment: @Chris Wesseling >"What the heck makes you think I would?" Oh, I dunno. Maybe because that's exactly what you said in the OP? I think it's high time that we stop making these communities into gladitorial rings. That's not the n00bs. That's US doing that. That's US being nasty, patronizing and often, downright brutal. I love this place. It has helped me out a lot. I try to give back. I have a lot to give back. So do you, and so do many new folks. However, I've nuked almost every social media account I have, because I don't have time for the childish BS that pervades the Internet these days.

Comment: BTW: I was helped out, just today, by someone with a very low SO score, but obviously lots of highly relevant experience.

Comment: The question has been marked as duplicate. But this question is older than the one it's marked duplicate of...

Comment: I believe this is the controlling position from Meta Stack Exchange: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Comment: I think this gets at the larger issue of how can we dissuade constant abuse of SO (e.g. with “write this code for me” / “debug my code for me”) questions when almost invariably people answer them. Why do people answer them? Likely from some combo of a desire to help and a desire for rep. If we eliminated the latter, I think it would help. I dare not suggest this via a Meta question out of concern for my rep, but one thought is to multiply the Question votes by the answer votes (obviously not letting negative * negative go positive) to obtain the rep delta for the answerer….

Comment: …so if the question has positive votes and your answer does too, you’ll gain rep, and more for a higher voted question and/or answer. If the question has net negative votes, then any answer with non-zero votes will result in a rep loss for the answerer, the magnitude being the product of the absolute values of the scores for the question and answer. So this way SO users would be disincentived from answering poor questions and their askers would be less likely to get what they want (often code with little to no work) despite violating the rules.

Comment: There could also be a small baseline rep penalty for answering a negative scored question just to make sure that even if the answer has no votes it’s a harm to the answerer’ rep. And honestly why should answering downvoted questions help your rep? Isn’t rep effectively a gamified metric of how much your actions help the SO community (asking good questions, providing good answers)? Answering poor questions helps no one and enables the cycle of abuse of SO.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

If the answer merits a downvote then downvote it.

Downvoting purely because you believe the question itself is off-topic is in my opinion counter-productive. It is perfectly possible to write a good answer to a broad question by informing the asker it is too broad but suggesting how they might break it down or resources they may find useful.

That is the sort of elitist community I do not want to be a part of. We should be thinking of ways to encourage new members not alienate them.

Comment: And that's also why we have the [reversal badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal)

Comment: I would say that merely informing the asker a question is too broad, and suggesting how they break it down, is **not** a good answer and should be a comment instead. A good answer should actually provide an answer to the question being asked, not simply describe ways of improving the question. I do however agree that answers shouldn't be downvoted due to problems with the question - questions/answers have their own vote buttons because they are separate.

Comment: If you can break it down and indicate what the answer would be to each section then you'd have an answer. "Too broad" means that the asker shouldn't have asked the question that way, not that no answer exists.

Comment: Oh, and I also think (although I expect this is controversial) that partial answers to any questions, whether "too broad" or not, can be useful both to the questioner and to future visitors. For example if a question is too broad because there are a myriad of different ways of achieving the goal depending on the exact details (which the questioner didn't supply), but there's one way that works for most people's exact details, and the pre-conditions can be clearly stated, then that's IMO a good answer to a "too broad" question.

Comment: @SteveJessop No. Too broad means that the answer cannot be answered in its current form because it is too broad to write a decent answer covering all bases. To critique a question use the comment section.

Comment: If the answer is not really an answer, but merely telling OP how to improve his/her question it should be downvoted.

Comment: " It is perfectly possible to write a good answer to a broad question by informing the asker it is too broad but suggesting how they might break it down or resources they may find useful."

Comment: @PeeHaa: I didn't say that.

Comment: Ow sorry. Totally wrong ping :-) That first ping should have been @george :P

Comment: @PeeHaa I dont think that too broad necessarily means the question -cannot- be answered, just that any answer would either be incomplete or so long it is poor for a Q&A format. If it makes good points and helps the op or other users there is still room for an upvote, though it would have been better for the person answering to have identified this and first edited the question or helped the op do so.

Comment: @PeeHaa I was referring to breaking down the problem into more manageable chunks so that the OP can attempt to find solutions themselves (i.e. thinking like a programmer). Perhaps the answerer doesn't agree the question is too broad either, we are assuming that everyone agrees on what is considered too broad.

Comment: Well said. What it ultimately comes down to is that these ARE newbies. Even if their question warrants a downvote, sometimes an answer (especially one that also teaches them how to write better questions) is helpful to them AND the community. Downvoting such answers definitely gives the air of "anti-newbie" (a topic I discussed in a speech last summer, actually.)

Answer (score 134):

Someone spent time answering an overly broad question and you want to "punish" him for not spending his time on some "better" question ? It sounds really harsh and arrogant.

We don't want bad answers nor bad questions but we **want answers** and we do not own the time of the people providing these answers. Closing the question is enough to avoid too many answers on bad questions.

As I see it downvoting an answer should only depend on the content of the answer itself: erroneous, not answering the question, too broad. And even in these cases I usually don't downvote as a reflex even for most obviously bad answers, I usually prefer leaving a comment saying how the answer could be improved.

I do not even downvote some answers much more annoying to me than the above one: multiple answers providing the exact same content as existing ones.

This is basically a way for me to encourage answering people that just weren't fast enough to publish their content... but sometimes we get answers identical to existing ones days after the initial answer. I suppose it happens when people give an answer without bothering to read existing ones. Even in this case I do not believe a downvote is appropriate. The guy that answered still spent his time doing it, and he should be thanked for that even if for once his answer is useless.

Comment: Yes, this, 1000x. Punishing someone for spending their own time writing the best answer they can to a question you don't like is really not useful. It doesn't make SO or the internet a better place.

Comment: Thank you for summarizing my comments on the subject. Indeed, we own our own time. And of course, everyone who invests considerable time on SO takes quality to heart. Let opinions differ, democratic voting prevail. Let's not be envious and wish to control our neighbour.

Comment: The site is not here to hand out gold stars for trying your best, and downvotes are not punishment. They are an indication to other readers that the post is not a good addition to the knowledge base.

Comment: @JoshCaswell this question is about whether (good) answers to bad questions should be downvoted. If the answer is good, then it is a good addition to the knowledge base. If you don't like the answer, downvote the answer. Judge the answer on its own merits. Yes? The issue here is precisely whether downvotes should be used as a punishment for someone having the audacity to spend their own time answering a perceived "bad" question. The OP's point is precisely treating downvotes as punishment, to discourage certain behavior.

Comment: @jalf, this Meta question says "well meant attempts to answer their parts, but **none really answers the question.**" (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: @Josh Caswell: off topic answer may legitimate downvote, of course. But **none really answer the question** is merely subjective. Sometimes the correct answer can be explaining why a question is bad. Typical case: "How can I do this" when "this" is something useless that should not be done at all...

Comment: @kriss Sometimes the correct *reaction* can be explaining why a question is bad... The nature of that reaction is a *comment*. But there are reasons for disguising it as an answer: they offer more room for markup and hence expressiveness; and have no chance of receiving rep through upvotes... And *this* is a reaction in a discussion more apt for chat, disguised as a comment... We all have our fallacies ;-)

Comment: @Chris Wesseling: I partially agree with your comment. Of course the line between comments and answers is not always something definite. It even happened to some of my questions that I got the actual best answer as a short comment... no way to accept it. Too bad. What I actually tried to point out was that sometimes to give a correct answer you have to choose between "correct" and "answer". How to respond to "When did you stopped beating your wife ?" if you never did that. In such cases correcting the question must be part of the answer.

Comment: **"Closing the question is enough to avoid too many answers on bad questions."** That's usually not the case, but I agree that downvoting *purely* for being an answer on a bad question is not enough to merit a downvote.

Comment: ""How can I do this" when "this" is something useless that should not be done at all" -- The X-Y problem is *always* presumed in favour of the answerer and against the questioner, at least by the answerer. Sure, that's the common case, but it's also fun to keep a look out for answers that say "this should never be done, because of principle Z", where principle Z in fact is something you personally think is false. The questioner might well think so too. You only get half points for spotting it if principle Z is some methodology dogma rather than a technical consideration :-)

Comment: ... so when I have the time I first answer the X question, explain what that's a bad solution to almost any plausible problem, *then* start speculating as to whether there's a Y problem that I can also solve in the answer.

Answer (score 23):

You can downvote whatever you like, for any reason you like.

But are the answers really the problem here? Or is the question too broad and should just be closed?

Comment: I agree, the question is the real problem. But isn't attempting to solve the Trolls riddle, considered feeding it, and hence part of the problem?... In the mean time this question even got upvotes, sucking more precious expert attention towards it.

Comment: @Chris, Questions that are too broad aren't all posted by trolls.  Some are posted by good-faith editors who don't know the ropes.  Questions like that might be OK to answer but best is to downvote the question and leave a comment that gives the question poster more guidance.

Comment: @La-comadreja, sorry I overloaded the meaning of Troll. I didn't mean the *intentional* part of trolling, just the posing riddles that eat resources part.

Comment: Gain rep fast, in 3 easy steps. 1) Go to the close-vote queue. 2) Answer a question. 3) Get upvotes. The community says "oh, you took the time to answer this! Good job.". OP says "thank you for answering this! Good job.". But the fact is that the answer (and question) have no value for the community. Any good answer takes too long to write so is blocked by the closing.

Comment: "You can downvote whatever you like, for any reason you like."... for _any_ reason?

Comment: This answer is pretty poor. Sure, the OP can downvote answers because he's having a bad hair day, if he likes, but do we really want to be _encouraging_ that behaviour, Mr. Moderator? (Hint: No)

Comment: This answer completely evades the actual question.

Comment: The question asks for an answer to the latter, @GeorgeStocker.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling "eat resources" - there's a fallacy there. You're assuming that there's a fixed pool of users interested in investing a fixed pool of time and they have no critical selection except for the "attention drawn by votes". In fact, I only frequent SO because I can hand-pick my finger exercises. I'll stop doing that once my answers get punished for being to question that "don't deserve it". It'll mean I stop frequenting SO. Focus: Freedom of speech. Democratic voting. Re. "sucking more precious expert attention towards it" -> The expert attention is not ***yours*** to control.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker We know the difference between `can` and `should`. Do you know the difference between `intention` and `perception`? (half joking :))

Comment: @ChrisWesseling "Eat resources"? What the.... My time is *mine*. You don't own it, and you don't get to decide which questions I spend it writing answers for. The only way to ensure sufficient "resources" for the *good* questions to get answers is to encourage people to write answers. Downvote my answer because you want to indirectly punish the person who asked the question, and I might just stop writing answers entirely. Heck, call me "a resource", and I might stop writing answers. You may have missed the part where SO is a volunteer community.

Comment: @sehe [RFC2119](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2119.html), great read. ;)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling used that in an answer yesterday :)

Comment: @jalf & sehe, I don't claim any control over your time. The wading through bad questions that everybody has to do during their hand-picking strikes me as wasteful.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling then don't do it... It's _your_ time (why is it not a problem for me, semi-professional SO answerer? I just downvote any badness in sight. Even if it's a +24 answer form 2008, like earlier today)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling look at what you said. You talked about bad questions "eating resources". In other words, they cause people to spend their time on the "wrong" thing. In making that judgment, you are laying claim to our time. You are telling us that we should not spend our time on writing *that* answer. Tell me that more than a couple of times, and I'll stop writing *any* answers, which means that I'll go from splitting my time between good and bad questions, to giving *neither* any time at all. Bad questions do not "eat resources". That is the wrong way to look at it.

Comment: If anything, come to think of it, bad questions typically *create* resources. They are typically asked by newcomers. The goal should be to make that newcomer *stay* on the site, while writing *better* questions in the future. That way you *create* resources. Making him (or those who answer his question) go away only *loses* resources.

Comment: @jalf They are the juice in the CDO's of SO, come to think of it. :)

Comment: By comparison, off-topic questions can eat resources if they require moderator attention. Because, while also donated time, I think it *is* reasonable to regard that as a site resource to be used as constructively as possible. The difference being that we don't tell moderators off for doing something we consider unproductive, we tell *other people* off for wasting moderator time.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, the bad questions can eat moderating resources.  The good answers to those questions don't, though.  It's downvoting the good answers to those questions that may eat moderating resources.

Comment: I downvoted this very answer "for any reason I like" -- just to make it self-referential.

Comment: Most of the time I see this behavior, yes; it's a question that should have been closed. Unfortunately, it just takes too long to close a question. People almost always burn effort and submit answers before the requisite five votes are reached. To be fair, most of that is a mad scramble to capitalize on the low-hanging-fruit duplicate questions.

Answer (score 17):

**All** answers to bad questions should be downvoted, whether they are correct or not.

When we answer bad questions, we reward the bad askers. Remember that gamification is a big influencer of user behavior site. We reward askers in a number of ways, most notably by giving them correct answers to their question. When we reward askers for asking bad questions, we reinforce their behavior. The result? More bad questions.

Most of the site regulars know that answering bad questions encourages bad questions. We should help to inform other users of the site by downvoting their answers, even when their answers are technically correct. This will remind them to stop encouraging bad behavior.

The downvote tab says "This answer is not useful." If the answer encourages bad behavior, it is definitely not useful.

Many hold the mistaken view that @sehe expressed in the comment below "*don't punish people for being good*." Consider a typical new user, Bob, who has a question that has been answered before. What will make Bob happiest: an customized, authoritative answer to his question, or a link to the canonical answer? If Bob gets an answer, he has been rewarded for his behavior. The site has worked as he expected it to work, and he will use it again *in exactly the same way*.

If instead, he sees only downvoted answers (or better yet, no answers) and a box containing a link to the canonical answer, Bob begins to understand that there is a better way to use the site.

We can encourage the better behavior in many ways: downvote Bob's question, mark it as a duplicate if appropriate *and* downvote the answers to make sure that all future Bobs ask better questions and get better answers.

Comment: I disagree. People have different opinions of what constitutes a bad question. If people use their time to volunteer help, they should not be punished for disagreeing with your opinion of what is "worthwhile". If the question is bad, it should be downvoted. That - in itself - will drive less traffic to the answers as well.

Comment: Does that mean we should down vote answers to duplicate questions?

Comment: In other words: don't punish people for being good. People will find out soon enough what answers get more appreciation. And if not, no harm done. Just ***downvote  the bad posts***, questions or answers alike.

Comment: @Abizern Which behavior do you prefer to encourage: proper use of the search functionality, or more duplicate posts? If the former, downvote. If an asker gets an answer to his duplicate question, the behavior has been encouraged and s/he will repeat the same action next time. If instead, the only useful response is a box at the top that says "This question already has an answer..." s/he will know to look harder before posting in the future.

Comment: You may be interested [in what has already been said about that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202895/should-we-downvote-answers-to-obvious-duplicate-questions), @Abizern.

Comment: The problem with this "conditioning" approach is that  you can't instill beliefs and values in people by oppressing contrary beliefs. You will have to lead by example.

Comment: A down vote with an explanation, then.  Bit we all know where that leads.

Comment: When you answer a bad question, you might reward bad askers. But when you downvote a good question, regardless of the quality of the *question*, you are discouraging and penalizing people who put effort into writing a good answer. Also, you're behaving kind of like an asshole. IMO, discouraging good answers is a far bigger crime than encouraging bad questions. SO depends on good answers. It will always get good and bad questions, but if you punish people for writing the best answer they can, they might stop writing answers. A good answer to a bad question is better than no answer.

Comment: @jalf "_SO depends on good answers._" I disagree. SO depends on good _question/answer pairs_. Good answers to bad questions help only the particular asker. They clutter the site, make good question/answer pairs harder to find, and encourage people to ask bad questions in the future.

Comment: > "If the answer encourages bad behavior, it is definitely not useful." - disputable, and many times highly subjective. There are good means to discourage bad behaviour. Analogously, would you say that **not** running over a pedestrian who runs the traffic-light is "encouraging bad behaviour"? I say, stop trying to control and judge others.

Comment: The exclusive purpose of voting is to judge others. That's exactly what it is and why it's here.

Comment: @George Cummins: I totally disagree with what you say. Good answers to Bad Questions is usefull to avoid further bad questions on that subject matter. For instance if it explains why it is a bad question, hints on ways to make the question more specific. A answer of the kind "This is a bad question because xxx, and you should ask yyy provide details, etc. to have a more specific answer" should be a visible answer, not buried in comments.

Comment: I deleted my comment because the question asks specifically about questions that are too broad, not dupes, so my argument didn't hold water.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins and how do you propose to get "good question/answer pairs", if you penalize people for writing answers? If you believe the question shouldn't exist, vote for it to be closed. Newcomers who write their first answer and have it downvoted **because they chose the wrong question to answer** aren't going to come back. On the other hand, people who write bad questions, get good answers *and* comments pointing out how they can improve their question might ask better questions in the future.

Comment: @jalf: sounds speculation to me. at the very least you should phrase it as "might not come back"

Comment: "an customized, authoritative answer to his question, or a link to the canonical answer?" - false dichotomy. A customized authoritative answer might defer to canonical answers for background (I do this). Also, it's quite funny that you are trying to justify the reasoning by asking the rhetorical question "What will make Bob happiest?" - if you take **that** as your guideline... That way lies crappiness. Of course, you can phantasize that all people will in the end learn to be like us, experienced elite SO users... But you know that's not the case (and it will _certainly_ not make Bob happy).

Comment: @DeadMG Primary purpose of voting on answers is to rank the answers, to grade them, evaluate them, provide community feedback on their validity. Judging means something a bit different.

Comment: Does anyone also think this post is ironic?

Comment: That's an awful lot of assumptions there, most of them obviously unfounded. A good answer to an overly broad question can be just as helpful to everyone as a good answer to a good question. And that's personal experience, not just an ex cathedra statement.

Comment: @jalf "people who write bad questions, get good answers and comments pointing out how they can improve their question might ask better questions in the future." I think we've tested this theory already. You may be right in some edge cases, but the evidence shows that the bad-to-good question ration is is huge and growing. That method isn't working, and I contend that it won't work until we stop the practice of providing the askers with what they want: valuable (but free) answers to lazy questions.

Comment: @biziclop In cases where a question is good enough to remain open (though perhaps not as good as we would prefer) you might be right: A good answer can help to inform both the OP and future visitors. However, in the case of questions that deserve to be closed, the answer will help the OP and others only during the short time period when the question remains open. Few (if any) others will benefit, and the process is repeated again when the OP asks another bad question hoping for the same results. Answers will provide a greater benefit on better questions that will remain open.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Once again, you're talking in absolute terms: "good enough to remain open" or "deserve to be closed", as if they were intrinsic qualities of the questions. They're not. I've seen many a question closed by what I perceived as overzealous voters and many where I wondered how we haven't managed to scrape 5 pesky votes together to get rid of it. And clearly your policy doesn't work, as the evidence shows. In reality, probably no policy would work because the problems run far deeper. And I'm certain that the power of gamification is massively overestimated.

Comment: There seem to be a bunch of users who are doing this regularly - downvoting answers to questions that are bad, or are duplicates.  Sadly, these people think they're doing the right thing.  I don't know whom they think they're punishing, or why; but they are certainly missing the point.  Perhaps it's time for the SO admins to step in and speak out against this behaviour.  It needs to stop.

Answer (score 7):

It's always *OK* to downvote a bad answer. The "too broad" close reason states that no good answer is possible unless it's too long for the site: if this is true then it follows that any attempted answer is either not good or too long. If not good it can certainly be downvoted. I think "too long" is intended to mean that it would take a book as opposed to an article to answer. So you're unlikely to need a general policy what to do with "too long" answers.

It's also OK to downvote answers-used-as-comments, although this questioner's answer on the linked question seems to have escaped that. Actually I think the last paragraph of that alone would have been a pretty reasonable "broad answer to a broad question".

I think would be wrong to go any further than "OK to downvote", and build a policy around what you "should" do to those who disagree with your close votes. That is, one should not systematically go through every answer to a question you have close-voted ("too broad" or any other reason) and downvote them all regardless of the content of the answer.

Not so much for the question you link to, but for a newly-closed question there ostensibly remains the possibility that it will be reopened. I doubt that many who chose to follow a systematic policy of down-voting would come back later to check on this and if necessary admit their error and request the answer be edited so that they can remove the (with hindsight unjustified) downvote. As such, it seems wrong to treat "this is too broad to answer" as an objective fact that others should be punished for not taking into account.

I think the specific comment you provide as example, is unfair/unhelpful if the answer was a "well-meant attempt to answer their parts". An on-hold question was not on hold when the answerer answered it. So even if in hindsight the community has decided that it was too broad, that was not established at the time and so the answerer has not done anything *procedurally* wrong. They just (let's suppose incorrectly) didn't agree that the question couldn't be answered. So it's not helpful to present "what they did wrong" in terms of information that they didn't have at the time.

Neither do I think it's good practice to go around telling people that because you close-voted a question, they must too.

If you must downvote then better (IMO):

> -1. This only addresses a few small parts of the question, which btw is too broad for this site anyway.

To your last remark: agreed, such comments would enforce the idea that SO is harsh to newbies. I don't see that as *inherently* the reason not to do it, my reasons for not doing it are different. SO is harsh to people who ask bad questions, give bad answers, or fail to follow the correct procedures. Newbies typically do all three. SO is harsh to newbies. It would be dishonest as things stand, to pretend otherwise. Of course one can try to enforce that while carrying out the solemn duty of being harsh to newbies, SOers must remain civil. And there are always a few SOers who try to mitigate the general harshness by encouraging and being very helpful to newbies.

You'd be applying principles very inconsistently to say that one specific behaviour should be avoided *because* it's harsh to newbies, when so many other behaviours and site features are harsh but are not avoided.

For example, newbies encountering the SO UI frequently use answers as comments because they can't comment yet. They can get downvoted for doing so and told the reason for the downvote. It's perfectly natural to perceive the comment block as a UI obstacle rather than what it is: a binding but rather surprising statement "you are trusted to answer a question as it stands, but not trusted to ask for the information needed to answer it". It's harsh, it's not necessarily how *I'd* have designed things, but it's how the system works, and it doesn't take much to get the rep to comment once you understand the rule. However, commenting to tell newbies they shouldn't even try to answer certain questions is a whole different thing from telling them they shouldn't use answers to workaround their comment ban, so I suppose one could argue about the precise *degree* of harshness to newbies that we want SO to express ;-)

Comment: "if this is true then it follows that any attempted answer is either not good or too long". This isn't true, they aren't a gospel, for this to be true a close voter would have to perceive all possible answers and know that every one is bad. These are just guidelines. We don't need policies, just common sense, do what you think is right.

Comment: @GeorgeReith: OK, but if you see an answer that is good and short and answers the whole question, then neither by common sense nor by policy should you be close-voting "too broad" :-)

Comment: "Answers the whole question"... This is where it becomes a guideline for me. If it provides a good answer to part of the question and has reason for not answering the rest then it is good enough for me. I certainly don't see how that warrants a down vote.

Comment: @GeorgeReith: well, the point of that part of what I said is that the answer should be downvoted on the basis of whether it's good or bad, same as answers to any other question. Now, it happens that if the "too broad" close reason applies then you won't expect to find any good answers, but as I say that doesn't mean downvote indiscriminately. I'd also say that if answers to part of the question are nevertheless good, then "too broad" shouldn't apply in that case either, but that's a matter of site organisation, how strongly to enforce that the question should be split up.

Answer (score 3):

Subjectivity aside, I would say that a comment under said question saying (nicely, that is) that the question is too broad and needs specificity while making clear what needs to be specified is the best way to approach this (at least initially). As a newbie myself, I can say for us newbies (or at least for me), that a definite impression of 'Us' and 'Them' can arise when we ask what [we think] are legitimate questions which are then down-voted for being 'too broad' or 'duplicate questions'.

It's not like we always know what is 'too broad', and after five or six tries at the search bar it is not hard to believe that whatever we are asking really isn't a duplicate question. Do you really think we go 'hey, here's a question that has already been answered, let me ask the same question worded differently just to waste everyone's time!'

Unfortunately, here are some adjectives that can be conveyed upon simply down-voting or marking as duplicate: 'short, strict, and blunt'. However, please remember that this is all subjective, and I can't say with 100% certainty about all of this.

But I digress. After the comment, the author could then edit the question to everyone's benefit. However, if the author is lax at improving the question, (lax meaning in this case after 24 hours or so), then everyone can put on hold, downvote, etc.

**Example**: "Sorry, but I'm not getting the question at the moment. Could you please specify part (xyz) further? Thanks".

Answer (score -4):

1. **Maintaining addiction to SO**. Whether you like it or not, StackOverflow is largely driven by people's habits, a certain kind of addictive behavior. Downvoting answers for reasons other than answer quality can weaken those habits and make people switch their energy to other channels. It may benefit a particular person who would spend more time with his family, but it would definitely not benefit the SO community. The "resource" lost by the person "answering the wrong question" is nothing compared to the "resource" lost by driving a person away from a website, and one negative experience would be enough for many people.
2. **Commitment to truth**. Since SO is an open community dedicated to providing correct information, I would consider truth, honesty an important value. Then on which grounds can we downvote a "good" answer to a "bad" question? After all, the answer is good, so if we are committed to being honest, shouldn't we acknowledge that? **Downvoting such an answer presumes that people answering questions should not answer "bad" questions, as otherwise they are doing a kind of disservice to the SO community**.

There are many problems with this approach. First, there is no clear agreement, which questions are "bad", and which are not, so now we are getting into a discussion, who is doing a service to the community (answer good questions), vs. who is doing a disservice to the community (answering bad questions). This brings a spirit of egoism, separation, if not hatred, as "disservice to the community" sounds pretty similar to "an enemy of the people".

Another problem is that it requires every person answering a question to evaluate, to judge this very question in terms of its broad usefulness to the SO. This is what moderators or editors are for. A typical user is not supposed to have the expertise to make a solid judgment as to what is useful to SO and what is not, much like a typical contributor to Wikipedia understands it much worse than a senior editor. Otherwise all answering will have to be done by a small group of senior members, and you'll get Encyclopedia Britannica instead of Wikipedia --- not what we are aiming for.

3. **Don't get too preoccupied with the rules**. I know that for programmers it is very tempting to create a world governed by fixed, well-defined rules. Yet life does not work this way; even for the physical universe such rules are only an approximation. I have encountered lots of perfectly useful questions on SO with perfectly valid and useful answers that were closed because of not conforming to some standards. For example, somebody was asking to recommend a particular library for some purpose. At the same time, deeply philosophical questions such as "What is a REST API?" are very popular and gets lots of attention and lots of upvotes.
4. **Human factor**. I am pretty sure that most downvotes on SO are ultimately not justified --- that is, that people downvote questions and answers because they had a bad day, because they want to feel smarter than somebody else, and so forth, while the particular questions or answers are actually useful and are serving the community, even though the particular downvoter is unable to see anything beyond his small perspective. I would instead suggest removing or severely limiting the whole downvoting feature, or perhaps displaying on one's profile the number of downvotes this person has ever done.

Bottom line: stop downvoting things. Stop worrying about resource consumption. Stop "consuming resources" by spending time on the Meta ;-) Focus on what you think is best, and other people will follow.