# What incentives are there to "game" Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

Reading this question [Should I downvote attempted answers to bad (too broad) questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252003/should-i-downvote-attempted-answers-to-bad-too-broad-questions?cb=1) on Stack Overflow, I noticed that one user (George Cummins) noted that:

> Remember, gamification is a big part of this site.

What real world incentive do people have to game this site?  I say "real world" because reputation points are in and of themselves worthless (apart from what they might do for a user's ego) unless they can be applied to a real world benefit.

In case this question is regarded as meaningless, I note that it might help users identify whether someone is gamifying the site if we knew what the benefits of doing so were.

Update: I do acknowledge that one value of reputation points is that you can set bounty and gain more control over the site (through editing etc).

Comment: You severely underestimate the value of reputation points, badges, etc. for gamification purposes.

Comment: @AnnaLear actually I think you misunderstand my question. I'm sure reputation points have a value for "gamification" purposes, but what is the value of gamifying the site? Is it that people with high reps get job offers?

Comment: Some do. It's hard to put a number on that. However, your assumption that real-world tangible benefits must exist in order for someone to do a thing is flawed. There are a lot of ways to derive personal value out of SO participation - learning new stuff, feeling good about helping people, etc. And some people just like to watch their numbers grow.

Comment: @Leahcim - People have got jobs as a result of participating in SO, but that was a side effect. People will do all sorts of stuff to make *their* imaginary number bigger than someone else's.

Comment: "reputation points are in and of themselves worthless" o.O What is going on in this world?!?

Comment: @codeMagic I also said "apart from what they might do for a user's ego".

Comment: the problem are not only "too broad" questions. There are also the "too specific" questions, like "how do I select a random element from a list of bananas that I fetched through the Orang Utan API by using function foo_bar()". And then there are all these 1 point anonymous users like user872384627843287364 who couldn't care less about reputation points.

Comment: I've had work out of my SO rep.  It's not anecdotal.

Comment: Don't know why this question got a downvote. It's about StackOverflow and therefore belongs on this site. Indeed, the question was occasioned by a remark of another user. Just because some people think the answer is obvious doesn't mean the question should be downvoted

Comment: Votes on meta are different - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @leahcim: The purpose of Meta sites is to discuss the main site and its operation, not people's psychological motivations.

Comment: @Leahcim Yes, recruiters now look at SO. I've had several this year mention my SO score. It's absurd IMHO, given the fact that I see *constant* gaming by high-rep users (answering things that are obvious dups / poor questions / homework / etc) to boost their imaginary internet points instead of downvoting / closing the Q ... but there you have it.

Comment: @BrianRoach You are assuming people are answering duplicates/poor questions for the points, but possibly they can easily answer it without having to take minutes to find a **good** duplicate that answers the question sufficiently. So their higher points might not be their goal, but it is simply the result of their way of working with SO.

Comment: I am wondering if you aren't confusing the terms _gamification_ with _gaming the system_ (as in: exploiting the system in a way it wasn't intended). Gamification, or the use of game thinking and game mechanics in non-game contexts to engage users in solving problems ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)) is core to how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I could easily answer *dozens* of questions daily that are dupes to inflate my imaginary internet points. But I don't, because I actually **care** about the site, its purpose, and its guidelines. That's my point. If you have a reasonably high rep, you're *fully aware* of what you're doing when you post an answer to something you certainly know has been answered dozens of times before; which is inflating your imaginary internet point total (for whatever reason) with a complete disregard to the site guidelines.

Comment: @BrianRoach I don't entirely agree with you. In a better world most if not all duplicates would get closed, but sometimes you aren't aware that the question is a duplicate, or - to repeat myself - the time spent searching for the right duplicate with a good answer takes way more time than giving a good answer (to offset the bad answers already posted to the question). I also think this - sometimes - is a better choice than closing duplicate to a question that is almost but not entirely duplicate.

Comment: There's no "better world". There's *the proper way to do things, as per the guidelines, FAQ, etc, etc*. If indeed it isn't gaming, and someone is too lazy to participate as the guidelines state (which is to recognize things as dups, or to do a simple search), then perhaps that person shouldn't participate. Or else the rules should be changed and "vote as duplicate" should be removed. I personally am going with the former.

Comment: [What aspects of psychology does Stack Overflow take advantage of?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56810/165773)

Comment: I would like to mention that I have had the occasion to post duplicate questions unknowingly. Sometimes I contest these questions when the fact gets pointed out not because there is a question that my question covered the same subject area but because the question that it supposedly duplicated was so poorly written or general as to be useless in my search for an answer to my question.

Comment: @fsmart That's a different issue, honestly. Although personally I find it rare that an *answer* to something marked as a dup doesn't cover what's being currently asked, overzealous close votes (and subsequent pile-ons) do exist. Editing the original question to specify *why* that's not he case is the right course there.

Comment: I'd like 100 buck SB card

Comment: The whole point of "gamification" is that playing the game *is* the reward. It's a way to motivate people by making achieving organizational goals seem like a game, for no other reason than because people like playing games.

Comment: A concept very well implemented by SO. Before SO there were *CodeProject*, *CodeGuru (forums)*, *MSDN forums* and a lot more, that have/had a simple rating system but were/are also very successful (ignoring the fact, that their emphasis is elsewhere/somehow different). When people do something for free, they want to see (often, not always) at least some appreciation. It is also psychological (see the link from @gnat) - [People are strange :-)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WftIhN5GxGk).

Comment: @Abizern Your anecdote proves it's not anecdotal?

Answer (score 53):

Incentives for getting reputation on SO are identical to those of "gaming the site" unless there are ways of catching "gamers".  They include but are not limited to:

1. Ego boost
2. Employment opportunities
   a. Employers might want proof of ability to actually program for example
   b. Employers might search SO for available high reputation programmers
   c. Independent consultants can list their businesses and websites with SO under profile.
3. Immunity from badmouthing of SO community. It was a pretty harrowing experience until I got past the first 100 rep points on SO. I was afraid to ask questions or answer questions because people tend to be less friendly. Not that I have much reputation now but people tend to much less likely to bite my head off if I say something they don't like.
4. This is really kind of a silly question. It is like asking, what are the benefits of having a good reputation?  It would be easier to list the answers to the question, *What aren't the benefits of having a good reputation?*

Comment: _pretty harrowing experience until I got past the first 100 rep points on SO_. During that period one learns `DO's` and `DO NOTs` and gets accustomed to how community behaves.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225149/are-you-doing-yourself-out-of-a-job-by-answering-some-of-the-questions-on-stack/225155#225155

Comment: I really love lists.

Comment: I view a high-rep user who don't follow the rules much more negatively than low-rep users who do the same - high-rep users should know better. I suspect most users are of a similar mindset (although there can certainly be exceptions). Being badmouthed is more about not knowing the rules than having low rep (even though the two are related - you could have a hard time getting more rep if you don't follow the rules).

Comment: I can confirm point 2b.  I've received offers from recruiters based solely on my SO profile.  Which isn't all that great in the scheme of things, so I'd be very surprised if it was rare.

Comment: Completely agree with point 3. People on SO are far too quick to bite the heads off of new members for not knowing 'da rules'. In some cases it's the equivalent of someone being shouted at on their first day of work for not knowing how to use the printer or not knowing where the spare mice are kept.

Answer (score 38):

"To gamify" and "to game" is not the same thing, and both can happen without relating to the real world. Don't worry, everything will relate to Stack Overflow.

#### What is "to gamify something"?

To gamify = to use elements of games in a non-game.

For example, getting numerical scores for actions is an element of games, but Stack Overflow is not a game. Nevertheless, Stack Overfow incorporates this game element. So Stack Overflow is gamified.

#### Who gamifies?

The designers of the non-game. For example, the designers of Stack Overflow choose to include numerical scores.

#### Why would they gamify?

Many game elements influence how people interact with the game. If you want to influence how people interact with a non-game, you can gamify it. For example, a numerical score can influence people to behave so that the score increases. The Stack Overflow designers presumably want users to ask good questions. So they arrange for good questions to give score increases.

Note that the influence of game elements on the behavior of people can be quite unrelated to "the real world". For example, achieving score increases can be rewarding even if no one else on the world knows about the score.

#### Ok, so what is "to game something"?

To game = to take unfair advantage of rules ignoring their intent.

For example, the intent of the score for upvoted questions is that people ask good questions. But the rule is that people get better score if their question is upvoted. So in order to game the system, two users can team up and ask lots of bad qestions and upvote the team partner's question. The get better score and more privileges, that is, unfair advantage.

#### Who games something?

Users of the system.

#### Why would they game the system?

Some common reasons:

1. To get the unfair advantage (for example, privileges on Stack Overflow)
2. Because gamification influences them to do it (for example, scoring on Stack Overflow)
3. Because they don't agree with the system but are forced to participate (for example, tax avoidance schemes).

#### Why should they not game the system?

If people game the system, the original intent of the rules is not achieved.

#### So what's the relation of gamification and gaming the system?

See reason two for gaming the system above: Gamification can influence users of a system to game the system.

To avoid bad effects from this, one approach is to cleverly align the rules with their intent so that "game the system" becomes identical behavior to "follow the intent of the rules".

#### Should we use gamification anyway?

Maybe. I don't know. Personally, I like it, and I feel that it can motivate me to interact more with a site. Apart from this feeling, I don't really know whether gamification is good or bad.

For this answer, I can just point out that if a system is gamified, it can be more tempting to game that system. But this is just one possible effect of gamification, and it might well be balanced off by other effects so that gamification is an overall win.

Comment: Excellent answer. You cut to the heart of the misunderstanding and provided a useful explanation of the system. I think your last two paragraphs are overbroad and neglect to recognize the usefulness of gamification, but the rest was very well done. +1

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: I tried to rephrase the ending to be less negative, but I want to avoid answering "Is gamification good or bad?" because it seems not in scope here, it wasn't the original question, and I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think where you fail to see the value of reputation points in the 'real' world is how you are defining 'real'.

Today, a great many things are virtualized and have no 'real' presence. A great many things have never had a 'real' presence. Money is a classic example, most of it doesn't exist physically anywhere. Your real world 'reputation' or esteem amongst your colleagues has no obvious physical manifestation, but it has a great deal of value. Worth more probably than your job title, another non-physical but incredibly important aspect of your life.

I guess the point I am trying to make is that Stack Overflow reputation has a value that is similar in many respects to the above examples. I have literally never spoken to a programmer in person who didn't know what Stack Overflow was, and so you can assume that employers are roughly the same. Their decisions could be (and anecdotally **are**) swayed by an impressive Stack Overflow account.* It also could make other colleagues respect your opinions on coding matters more if they know that others also do.

On top of that, as you point out, you can almost 'buy' answers to difficult questions using the bounty system and spending points that you have earnt. I would say that Stack Overflow reputation holds a great deal of value.

*That's not to mention Stack Overflow Careers, where applicants will quite obviously have their account reputation on display.

Answer (score 8):

I will tell you few reasons why I started to answer questions on Stack Overflow. I am not the fan of points and badges, also I have some of them. I also have pretty good job, so I am not here to find an employer.

- I use Stack Overflow as a way to learn new topic. I started to learn [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), and right after this I tried to answer question on this topic. Why? Because also may be I think I know the answer, it might be not the best or even completely wrong. When I post my answer, other people (who might have more knowledge) will improve it or tell me that I am wrong. I do it with all things I try to learn (some JavaScript library, security concepts or other things).
- Sometimes I post answers just because I found a new (better) way of doing something. For example, I found a [two times improvement for finding distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21623256/1090562) (I needed it for my own project). Most probably I will forget about how I have done it (or will have some files laying on my computer with this function). But I can just post it here and will be able to find it in seconds (like I have done right now). Also, as a surprise, someone found my answer and improved it, and right now I have three times improvement (first point in my list - I learned something new).
- I review others answers (selecting to review only questions from topics I am interested in) to see what problems people have, and to make sure that I do not do such problems.

So as you see, you can get something tangible even without points. And as a last point, you can use your imaginary points to give bounties, and to tell the truth, where else would you see professionals, getting few hundreds dollars per hour, spending their time for 200 points of reputation? So your imaginary points are not so imaginary :-).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answers the question. The OP is looking for reasons why people might game the system, but this answer seems to just explain why you (as a nice fellow) use the site *despite* all the points.

Comment: Yeah, I went through a phase of answering. I suppose this might count as 'gaming' the system as I certainly got a massive boost in rep. Anyway, avatar upvote. +1.

Answer (score 4):

I spent a couple of weeks answering a lot of questions on SO around a year ago, I built up some reputation points pretty quickly and was in the top 2% for that month. A few weeks later I got an email from Google about job opportunities, and then had a phone interview (which I blew completely).

I have also recently seen job adverts where part of the application is to submit a link to your stack overflow account. For someone who might not necessarily be a coder but needs to hire one, a peer-awarded points system is a pretty good indicator of how competent that person is.

Comment: `of how competent that person is.` or rather `how much time someone spent on SO`....

Comment: I'm not saying it's the only indicator, or that someone with a rep of 100,000 is certainly more competent than someone with a rep of 200, but an employer can see whether fellow programmers have found a potential employee's advice useful. Google got in touch with me when I had a reputation score of 400. I hadn't answered many questions (still haven't) but I had upvotes on the one's I had answered.

Answer (score 3):

> What real world incentive do people have to game this site?

I don't understand your question. People play games for sport all the time. What real world incentive do people have to play video games or chess or pool for hours on end? Usually, none at all. But it's fun and challenging - sufficient motivating factors for just about any human endeavor.

I personally use SO for quickly solving problems I encounter in my work or side projects, and I contribute answers sometimes, if I think I know the answer, particularly for confused beginners - "Do unto others".

But at times, I just look for questions to answer, because it's fun and challenging, just like any other game.

Answer (score 2):

"What real world incentive do people have to game this site?"

Bounties. People will want high-rep to be able to place bounties on their own question, when in need. Getting useful answers on questions can spill into the real-world, such as fixing your system or finishing to build your software. And people can start to cheat in order to achieve as much rep as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I started registering and posting on SO at all is because I happened to find the majority of the eventually useful answers to my programming problems via search engines on SO. I just want others to be able to share this experience. After all it's shared knowledge and sources on the net that made me the techie I am today ^^

Reputation points are of course a great feature, especially because of the game aspect. In introduces a layer of sporty competition to the technical global commons without creating the nasty monopoly situations from the cut throat world of proprietary closed source patent troll shark pond.

Last but not least: I started playing with computers because of games to begin with, but no riddle or challenge in a pre-fab game ever beats real tech riddles and challenges. In that sense tech (also outside of SO) *is* a game environment.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer addresses the question.

Comment: @Duncan,really? The question is what incentives there are to parttake here as a non anonymous user collecting 'reputation' and badges. I believe (and explained in the answer) that the incentive is adding knowledge to the commons, that tech is a thrilling game and that these blend really well together ...

Answer (score 0):

> I say "real world" because reputation points are in and of themselves worthless (apart from what they might do for a user's ego) unless they can be applied to a real world benefit.

Really!  Ask Jon Skeet who is now probably one of the most famous and recognised programmers in the world along with Linus Torvalds, Richard Stallman and Joel Spolsky!