# When should we downvote answers?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, answers

I [answered an off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907568/display-selected-value-on-a-drop-down-list-using-javascript-or-php/23907647#23907647) with a correct answer and ended up getting -2 votes (2 upvotes and 4 downvotes).

The downvoters' reason for downvoting the answer was:

> Answering these type of questions will encourage users to ask questions without trying anything..A simple Google search of the question title will give many results.

However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), we should downvote answers if it is `clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect`.

So, is it valid for people to downvote answers of off-topic questions?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252003/should-i-downvote-attempted-answers-to-bad-too-broad-questions?rq=1

Comment: @NiekHaarman That is for questions that are too broad, not for questions that are off-topic

Comment: Also related: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions) I personally agree with you, but others have a different point of view.

Comment: [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)

Comment: Note that your answer have no good explanation on how it could be related to OP question (I'm not exactly sure what OP wanted in "program outputs the value of the list item"), uses random variable name (`strUser` is really related to months names?) and show not necessary good practice of using hardcoded IDs to select elements (i.e. over class names).  You definitely put effort in it and down-vote reason is questionable, but in current state it probably should stay about 0 anyway.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what's wrong with hard-coded IDs? They're faster than classes and often more semantically correct.

Comment: @JanDvorak off-topic on off-topic... I hope I did not said "wrong"... Harder to deal with multiple similar controls (like table of similar elements), may need IDs passed from server code thus possibly mixing HTML with JS... But it just personal opinion from ASP.Net person - original question was in PHP tag where it should not matter.