# Downvoted for giving a detailed answer

Tags: discussion, voting, downvotes, specific-answer

Once in a while I see users downvoting correct answers and sometimes good answers. The reason for this action being that they are addressing a seemingly bad question.

A similar issue happened to me today: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166362/jscrollpane-not-working-no-suitable-constructor-error/41166615?noredirect=1#comment69536461_41166615*

While I appreciate this user for leaving an explanation for the downvote, but I find his explanation kind of ridiculous.

> This question should never have been asked and definitely should not get a detailed answer like this.

**So my question is**: Can I flag for a moderator's intervention or is there nothing I can do and just bear with it? Is there any official or semi-official document from Stack Overflow on when a downvote (against an answer) should be casted?

---

This is not a duplicate of *[Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions)*.

I am talking about users asking basic questions with direct answers and not off-topic questions.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Should 'drive by' downvoting be more effectively caught?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/215379/335772)

Comment: It's gone now, but I suspect you got a down vote for answering at all and the "not get a detailed answer" was more about them feeling the question didn't deserve that much effort. I don't think they meant that a short answer would have gotten an up vote from them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions), http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252003/should-i-downvote-attempted-answers-to-bad-too-broad-questions

Comment: It's another flawed thing on SO. We all just learned to live with it. I've even seen ways to avoid downvotes (and apparently mods don't care about that) so yeah, don't take that things like that too seriously because, as I said, everyone eventually learns to live with them.

Comment: +18/-17 Downvoting of helpful answers is probably one of the most contested topics on meta stack overflow...

Comment: I believe this is the controlling position from Meta Stack Exchange: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Answer (score 20):

This is something I've talked about previously, so I'll quote [my answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/19679):

> I'll refer you to [my answer from earlier today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255782/shouldnt-we-revert-reputation-gains-for-answers-to-closed-questions/255805#255805), where I articulate this in a little more detail, but I believe that attacking people who answer bad questions is ultimately counterproductive. Everyone makes the assumption that if we stop answering bad questions they'll stop coming. I do not believe this is the case.
>
> The kind of people asking bad questions won't care if we stopped answering bad questions, because they don't realize their questions are bad and because they are desperate to have people do their work for them. These are the same people who posted dozens of terrible programming questions to Meta every day (until the reputation requirement kicked in), despite not a single programming question there being answered (or even allowed to live more than a couple hours).
>
> One thing I can tell you is that if you start targeting downvotes at experts who are just trying to help, you will start to drive those people away. I've already seen this in a few cases. These experts are the ones helping to provide great content for this site, and I want to do what I can to keep them feeling welcome here.
>
> I strongly believe that downvotes should *only* come based on the quality or correctness of the post you are voting on, and nothing else. Not because of the person leaving the post, and not as a warning to discourage them from answering questions you consider to be bad. It's up to you as to how you choose to vote, but that's my take.

I believe they were incorrect in going after you for trying to be helpful. If they want to deal with the question itself, fine, but attacking subject matter experts for providing good content will only make things worse by driving them away. It will do nothing to stop bad questions from being asked.

If you see comments berating answerers like this, you can flag them and I'd remove them. We can't see or change votes, and ultimately people can vote how they want, so there's nothing we can do about that part of it.

Comment: "*Don't bite the hand that feeds you.*" Without Answer-ers, questions are to no purpose. A site of Qs with no As would not last long.

Comment: @Brad Larson I totally agree with you.Unfortunately that user has been going around down voting good answers for quite a while.

Comment: Long thread about something unrelated [moved to chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1062/discussion-on-answer-by-brad-larson-downvoted-for-giving-a-detailed-answer).

Comment: Answer quoting an answer referring to another answer... awesome.

Answer (score 11):

> Can I flag for a moderator's intervention

No.  Users are given very wide latitude on how they're *allowed* to vote.  There are a handful of behaviors that are considered "voting fraud" that would merit flagging, but this wouldn't qualify.  Voting fraud would be someone voting for themselves with multiple accounts, or a clear indication that they're voting based solely on the author, not the post's content (basically, going around mass upvoting or mass-downvoting a user's posts from their profile).  This clearly isn't applicable to your situation.

> or is there nothing I can do and just bear with it?

Well, in this particular case the person happened to comment on your answer, explaining why they felt your post merited a downvote.  You could have discussed  the matter with them to better understand why they felt your post wasn't helpful, or to convince them of why you felt your answer *was* useful.  It's not much, but it's about all there is.  Users are, again, given very wide latitude on how they're allowed to vote, so while you can disagree with them, and you're allowed to vote the way *you* want, there isn't much else you can do.

> Is there any official or semi-official document from Stack Overflow on when a downvote (against an answer) should be casted?

Officially, you should be voting up an answer when it is useful, and voting down an answer when it is not useful.  Now, this is *guidance* as mentioned, not a rule anyone has any ability to actually enforce.  That said, it should be clear here that the *reason* there's so much latitude for voters is that it's inherently extremely subjective to determine whether or not a post is *useful*.  This is a very important point here.  It's not (just) about whether or not the post is *correct*, or whether or not the post is *detailed*.  There are *lots* of (other) factors that influence whether or not a post is *useful*.  Here are a handful of factors to take into consideration when determining how *useful* a post is; note that some are obvious, and most everyone uses them, and others are more subtle and overlooked by many voters:

(I'm going to limit these to answers, not questions, here)

- Is the information correct (or are any inaccuracies significant and/or inhibiting)?
- Does it answer the question?
- Is it a *complete* answer to the question?
- Is it clear?  (A great answer that readers can't understand isn't useful)
- Does it have security vulnerabilities?
- Will it successfully scale beyond the simple example given? (This includes performance, but also maintainability, memory footprint, or any other issues that might come up with less trivial examples.)
- Is the content applicable to a wider audience, or is it limited to just the specifics of the question asked? (Remember, we're creating a repository of knowledge here, this isn't a help desk.)
- Is it duplicating other content, rather than adding original information?
- Is it using good practices, or advocating harmful practices?

There are of course others, and these factors will all be weighed together to determine whether or not the post ends up being, in total, useful or not.  A major security vulnerability may well make an otherwise correct answer *extremely* harmful, and not at all useful, while an answer that's maybe less clear than it could be is *less* useful than you might like, but may well still be a useful answer in total.  This all falls on a spectrum.

You mentioned two of these points in your question, specifically "correct" and "detailed". Yes, those are qualities that one would expect to see in a useful answer, but they aren't the *only* qualities one would expect to use in a useful answer.  The person that commented on your answer brought up a few points specifically.  He felt that your answer wasn't useful because it was merely duplicating information already readily available in the language's documentation, and as a result not contributing to SO being a repository of helpful content.  Now, this is subjective.  You may disagree about whether or not that particular quality makes an answer entirely not useful, but the person voting was clearly following SO's guidance and was voting based on whether or not the answer was useful.

---

Whew.  That was a lot.  Notice how through all of that, we didn't actually bring up the question.  As has been mentioned by others, you should of course be voting on a post based on whether or not *that post* is useful.  We don't want people going around downvoting every single answer to every low quality question just because that question is low quality, we want them to downvote answers because *those answers* aren't useful.  Having said that, it's important to consider what makes a question a good question; why are questions that merit closure closed, and why are low quality questions low quality?

We close questions because the questions that meet our closure criteria are *extremely* likely to result in low quality answers.  When a question is "Too Broad", answers are virtually never complete, they're very often missing lots of important information that would go into a quality answer, and it also makes *finding* what information that's there almost impossible if the question actually does attract even a signification portion of what might make a complete answer, because trying to sift through a 30 page long answer to find the one paragraph that's actually relevant to any given problem is really hard (in the unlikely event that you actually get a 30 page answer).

When questions are unclear, they tend to attract lots of guesses, information that we can't actually determine whether it's applicable or not, and lots of competing theories as to what the question is actually asking.

When questions are asking for product recommendations, they tend to just attract tons and tons of spam, get outdated super quickly, and the answers tend to be no more than, "try this product" rather than actually containing enough information to actually determine which product(s) fit which situations, or why you might pick one over another.  Other sites tend to review products better, so SO chose to leave it to them.

And then there's your example.  In your case, the question is simply asking for information readily accessible in the language documentation, and got an answer just regurgitating the information found in the language documentation.  This answer isn't actually going to be helpful to anyone.  If anyone actually searches for what the signature of this constructor is, they're going to find the language docs, with all of the information needed and good examples of what to do.  They're not going to find your answer, and even if they did end up finding your answer instead of the documentation, they're not any better off.  You haven't improved the information available to programmers searching for solutions to their problems.

So yes, in the end, we don't downvote answers because the question is bad, but you should expect that if the question *is* bad, odds are *very* high that the answer is not going to be useful.  While it is *possible* to take a low quality question and create a useful answer out of it, it's rare.  You certainly shouldn't be surprised that if you come across a low quality question, it will have low quality answers, and likewise, the *reason an answer isn't useful* is often rooted in underlying problems with the question.  That doesn't mean that a downvote on the answer is "misdirected rage at the question" though; it's simply a result of the fact that problems in a question *very much affect the quality of an answer*, and those quality problems *with the answer* will very often result in it not being useful, and meriting downvotes.

Comment: +1 for a really thorough defense of downvoting (most) answers to (most) bad questions.

Comment: Ironically, you have written a long answer that contains implicit criticism of long answers.

Comment: @CodyGray Agreed, although it's worth noting that there are ways to at least...mitigate the problems with an overly long answer.  For example, I was very careful about how the information was ordered.  I front loaded the answer to the question, with the specific actionable information, and then expanded on that answer, focusing on the most important points to understand that answer and moving on to less directly related points, rather than spending a lot of time setting up to an actual answer buried 3 paragraphs down.

Answer (score 8):

Voting should be based on the quality of the post itself (in this case, an answer), not the quality of the question or other answers.  Users can downvote whatever they want for whatever reason, but in general voting should be on quality and helpfulness.  We have the [reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge for upvoted answers to downvoted questions after all.  In this case I would flag the comment as not constuctive.

As for flagging, no, you cannot flag.  Well, you can do whatever you want, but I suspect (as a non-mod) that your flag will be declined.  This is not a situation that requires moderator attention.  If someone did not find your answer useful for whatever reason, they can downvote.  It's -2 rep, they will tell you to get over it.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for giving downvotes is in the tooltip of the downvote arrow:

> This answer is not useful

If it isn't useful to Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow to have that question on the site then answering it isn't useful to the site as a whole. It encourages simple questions as people will realise they get answers to them. The more simple questions that could be answered with a quick Google (or just RTFMing) the more noise it creates on the site, drowning out actual useful questions.

To answer your question "can you flag it for moderator intervention": No. Moderators aren't there to judge if a downvote was for the 'right' reasons, and they can't do anything about it anyway.

Comment: "This answer is not useful" means "It's unlikely to help the problem as stated". While we realize that asking sometimes takes the place of searching, and we're taking measures to cull that, penalizing someone for failing to sour the milk even when their answer has merit is antithetical to everything I thought we built.

Comment: @TimPost It depends on your viewpoint I guess. Are we here to help individuals, or are we here to help communities as a whole?

Comment: I don't see the two as mutually exclusive.

Comment: @TimPost You think indicating that content is useful, even when it is not in fact useful, and it's not actually helping the community accomplish any of its goals, and is, in fact, *harming* the ability of the community to accomplish its goals, is antithetical to the communities goals?

Comment: @TimPost When what an individual wants involves harm to others, then they are in fact mutually exclusive.  Not every person in the world's goals are perfectly aligned.

Comment: From the http://stackexchange.com/tour page: 'we build libraries of high-quality questions and answers.' The overall aim of the sites (in my opinion) is it to be a repository of high quality content. Not *any* content.

Comment: It takes time for the 'community' to determine if a Question is on-topic, etc or not. More time than it takes to answer. The only way to reconcile these points of view is if everyone waited "a while" to see if the Question remained open before answering. This seems to be what this answer says to do...? This is what you want to happen? Maybe all Questions should simply wait 24 hours before Answers could be posted. This would sharply discourage the "get a quick answer here" syndrome. Why didn't someone propose that before? It would probably solve the FGITW problem, too.

Comment: @TimPost - "*This answer is unlikely to help the problem as stated*".... can this be the new downvote tooltip? :)

Comment: @OOO This question got speedy-deleted (closed, -3 and 3 20k delvotes), so it wasn't especially controversial that it was terrible. Avoiding blatantly terrible questions is not rocket science, especially for someone with almost 10k.

Comment: *failing to sour the milk* @TimPost - Googling this phrase wasn't very helpful. What does it mean to *fail* to sour milk?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I feel that voting should be based on the usefulness of the answer. To define usefulness, first of all it must be addressing directly to what Original Poster asked and whether it can solve the raised problem.

If the problem can never be solved, then that question clearly has a problem such as "question being too broad".

Be it the question is being vague, too broad or too basic. I would not down vote a good answer simply because that answer is useful (it is correct, it address to the problem, and it solves the problem).

I always believe down votes should be cast on bad questions, and not a good answer addressing a bad question.

As for the saying that answering basic questions encourage laziness. I agree to certain extend but disagree from the view point of StackExchange.

If you look at the questions which are 6-7 years old, many of those are highly upvoted basic questions such as "why this switch-case doesn't work".

But it is such basic questions which have helped numerous novices every year.

Comment: Right. One person can post an Answer. But it takes multiple people to cast enough votes, flags, etc to determine if a Question should stay on the site. What is one person to do in the meantime? Not participate? Do we penalize individuals for know being able to read the group's mind?

Answer (score -9):

Before downvoting, I suggest people ask themselves just why they are doing so.  And whether they really are qualified to speak for the whole community.

For new users like me, a comment is all it takes to cause me to simply edit my question or answer.

But once a question goes negative, you earn the "peer pressure" badge if you delete it, so for me, I edit it and hope for upvotes.  Then put it out of my mind and move on.

Never give up - this community has too much to offer to just quit.  Have the confidence to learn the ropes and keep on truckin'

Comment: There's not really any shame in deleting your own post if it's low scoring. That's why you get an award for doing so. It helps ensure the content across the sites is at a high quality.

Comment: Good point.  I have never enjoyed peer pressure.  I prefer to keep working on my answers or questions until I get it right.  Very often I find (in comments) that I had a fundamental flaw in preconceptions, so the end result is good learning.  Upvote for that thoughtful comment.

Comment: This answer appears to be another one of those whines against downvotes ("just leave a comment instead of downvoting!"), albeit a well-hidden one. All such pleas fundamentally misunderstand the purpose of votes: to rank content. Commenting and voting are orthogonal activities. I might comment on something that your answer could improve, or I might downvote because something is wrong with it, or I might do both. Fixing your answer in response to comments is great. Re-evaluating your answer in response to downvotes is also great. Why, exactly, should we avoid downvoting, then?

Comment: *"And whether they really are qualified to speak for the whole community"* Since when do voters speak for the whole community?

Comment: Where do you find that quote, @Gray?  Your comment is based completely on your imagination and not what I wrote.  I never said not to downvote.  My answer clearly mentions a way that comments are helpful.  And I wind up by saying not to worry about the downvotes.  In the end, the answers go into the community whether you downvote them or not.  And if a comment or two can cause a revision that is more useful, then so much the better.