# Meta.SE content should be discoverable on Meta.SO

Tags: feature-request, search, mso-mse-split

Since the new Meta.SE was introduced, many discussions have come up on Meta.SO that already exist on Meta.SE.

As [this answer by Tim Post shows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251428/187606), this is somewhat intentional and not viewed as a bad thing in itself.

To some extent, that's fine.  It's good for broad "political" ideas  to be rehashed and rediscussed many times in many different constituencies. It would be wrong to close down a lively Meta.SO discussion about mandatory downvote explanations just because it has been had on Meta.SE years before. I get it.

But some duplication can also be incredibly silly, and a waste of time for everyone.

Feature requests that already exist, often already critiqued and refined in painstaking detail over *years*, are getting posted again and again on Meta.SO now, because people (understandably) don't search the global Meta before posting.

That's bad. I would feel incredibly frustrated investing an hour composing a feature request, only to be made aware afterwards *that the same thing was already suggested in 2010.*

Please at least give users a chance to discover existing content before they post.

Both the site search, and the real-time "Questions that may already have your answer" dialog that pops up when you enter the question title, on Meta.SO **should also include content from Meta.SE.**

The real-time list should be a composed view between Meta.SO and Meta.SE, perhaps with an icon to mark Meta.SE questions.

[image]

This will not *always* lead to optimal results, but a well-tweaked ruleset - mandating for example that at least 50% of results must *always* come from the local site - should make it workable.

Comment: Actually this might benefit *all* site meta's as potentially things like explaining down-votes are likely to come up everywhere.

Comment: I'm actually really surprised the system didn't find duplicates for "WHY WAS I DOWNVOTED I HATE THIS SITE YOU ALL SUCK", people ask it here all the time.

Comment: I know the tooling does not exist for this, but I think it would be perfectly sensible to be able to close as an exact duplicate of a question on Meta.SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching in any meta site should include results from Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230105/searching-in-any-meta-site-should-include-results-from-meta-se), on, uh, MSE. :-) (And Nick's comment there gives us some hope: *"I think this makes a ton of sense - I'll bring it up in the team call today. We're in the midst of upgrading elastic to 1.10 before our data center move so it may be delayed a bit until that's complete (library updates, pull requests and such in play) but hopefully we can do something good here."*)

Comment: @Arjan : More of the same independent iteration. His explanation, with pictures! is quite close to how i envisioned it to be. Except that i was not limiting my scope to "question title" but searches as well. (note i'm not saying its a copy, he might have thought the same idea separately, originating from the same question too!)

Comment: @Arjan So we have a duplicate meta post, about how to to reduce duplicate meta posts. lol (sounds like we really need this feature)

Comment: And if this works well, then please even consider referencing SU and SF from SO. (I don't think the reverse is useful as well, but then: if search works well, it would then simply not find any matches.)

Comment: Too bad MSO does not allow for bounties! (And my reopen vote for [Searching in any meta site should include results from Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230105/searching-in-any-meta-site-should-include-results-from-meta-se) on MSE expired.)