# Make clear before asking that there are two Meta sites

Tags: feature-request, mso-mse-split

I see plenty of new questions getting asked on Meta.SO that are duplicates of older discussions that now often reside on Meta.SE.

I don't think that is a desirable thing in itself. New questions seem to often get a *lot* less discussion, input, and viewpoints than the "original" conversations.

One reason for this happening is that askers aren't actively pointed towards Meta.SE when asking a question on Meta.SO.

There should be a banner on top of the "Ask question" form that says something like this:

> **How to decide where to ask on Meta Stack Overflow (Meta.SO) or Meta Stack Exchange (Meta.SE).** Meta.SO is for questions that are specific to Stack Overflow and its community. General questions and feature suggestions related to the Stack Exchange Q&A model should go on Meta.SE. Click here to read more.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260101/244519

Comment: @Dronehinge good find. In that case, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252290/meta-se-content-should-be-discoverable-on-meta-so should be implemented though....

Comment: The *finding* of existing content is a different matter than where to post, though, in either case.

Comment: I have tried many times to get something positive done towards making previous MSO content available to MSO. Hopefully this will help address some aspect of that, because all of the discussions held on mSO ( that are now on MSE ) which are still relevant here really should be easier to find instead of frequently rehashing the same debate and topic. I even tried to make a small group of links to the most popular ones in a post but I guess that was the wrong way to go about it (10k+ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287922/1026459)

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't need to remind people about that.  There's nothing wrong with a question that could pertain to the entire network being posted on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com); people that only know about this site [are welcome to post issues here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251375/meta-hasnt-changed-at-all/251428#251428).

Of course, issues that could pertain to all sites are also welcome to be posted on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) - but as Tim pointed out in the above-linked answer, there's nothing wrong with posting them here first.  If nothing else, the presence (or lack) of support on [meta.so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) could be an indicator of the reception a suggestion will get over [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

In particular, it's clear that there is perceived value from having separate per-community discussions of things that might affect the entire network.  Pointing everyone to [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) would diminsh that discussion.

Comment: This is beside the point. The thing is that people searching for existing duplicates before posting don't think to search for them on Meta.SE, as well, because they don't know it exists. That leads to a lot of duplication unwanted even by the OP themselves. The issue is not new questions getting asked here or there

Comment: I don't see how that banner would have any impact on that.  Given the way per-site metas currently work, plus the answers like Tim's above, it's obvious to me that at least the SE staff believe it's better to _not_ point out the [meta.se] link, and let individual sites each discuss changes separately.

Comment: The way it seems to currently work is: 1. Someone posts a feature request 2. someone else points out a Meta.SE link to an identical or very similar feature request 3. the OP says "oops, sorry, I did search but didn't know there was a Meta.SE" 4. the discussion loses steam (because it's been talked about elsewhere), perhaps a couple points make it to the new question, perhaps not, and the question somehow lingers on in eternal limbo. Not a desirable outcome IMO