# Why is it not possible to down/upvote questions in the close vote review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, voting

Why can't I down-/up-vote questions in the close review queue (what is the rational behind it)?

Is it good / bad practice to open the question in a separate tab and vote on it there?

Comment: MSE post: [Up/down voting on questions in the close votes review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211641/up-down-voting-on-questions-in-the-close-votes-review-queue)

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Thanks, forgot to look there - which gives me an Idea for a feature request: Show possible duplicates from other SO sites, when asking a question.

Comment: That feature-request would be a dupe as well :) Let me see if I can easily find that.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252290/meta-se-content-should-be-discoverable-on-meta-so and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230105/searching-in-any-meta-site-should-include-results-from-meta-se