# Should we downvote, flag or leave comments on Spam?

Tags: support, spam

An hour ago we had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323054/open-blocked-twitter-in-turkey) (only visible for 10K-ers now) spam post on the site.

In a chatroom that post was brought to my attention.

When I loaded the post it had a comment and 6 downvotes. I expected to be the last one needed to flag the post as spam because every spam flag casts a downvote as well. To my surprise after I flagged as spam the post didn't disappear. It needed another 6 spam flags apparently to finally be deleted by the Community user.

I always assumed flag as 'spam' was enough. No downvotes, comments or close votes needed, nor edits on the post.

Has the policy or community consensus for spam posts changed?

Comment: It probably got some plain downvotes, not originating from spam flags.

Comment: That must be downvotes from users with less then 15 reputation (required rep to be able to flag)? Which can't be true because downvoting requires 125 rep...

Comment: Some people just may not realize it's more effective to flag spam than to downvote. For new folks, it's not all that obvious.

Comment: @rene: remember users can cast downvotes in _addition_ to the downvote cast by community when they flag a post as spam.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they can and that is fine. But having a spam post with 6 downvotes and no spam flags is a missed opportunity by 6 users. I think an answer to my question should include that...

Comment: Downvote arrows are obvious. Flag link hides below the question itself, and many users are not aware it even exists.

Comment: Based on the comments I would say we want to have more exposure to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for users that downvote a spam post?

Comment: As Michael said, many people don't realize that you really do need to flag spam, not just downvote it. I see this commonly in the Late Answers and First Posts review queues, where certain reviewers will only downvote spam, not flag it, and that spam then is allowed to live on the site. Not quite sure how to educate people like that, short of the bans that I sometimes hand out when I see this.

Comment: @Brad Another problem with the review queues, though, is that people aren't actually *looking* for spam. They just glance at it and assume it's a crappy answer and downvote it thinking that's all that needs to be done, not paying attention to the fact it's spam and should be flagged. It's called robo-reviewing.

Comment: Maybe add a dialog at the top of the flagged post that says `This post was flagged as spam. If you agree, please flag it as spam as well.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, flag it for spam.  This way, it can get moderated appropriately.

Downvotes are helpful too, as it reduces the overall visibility of the question itself on the front page.  This potentially helps reduce the footprint of others potentially clicking on the link.

Comment: My question is not about what to do. My question is why 6 users didn't do that before I arrived on the post.

Comment: How do you know?  The spam flag isn't made visible to anyone but moderators and internal system processes.  All six of 'em could have flagged it for spam, or none of them could.  We can't know that just by inference.  What I'm suggesting here is independent of anyone else that participates/sees a post like that - flagging for spam is paramount, and downvotes can help too.

Comment: My point is that users with enough rep to downvote (125 rep) a spam post should at least leave a spam flag as well (flagging requires 15 rep).

Comment: Again, I maintain that you don't know for certain that they *didn't*.  That is, unless you could demonstrate to me otherwise...?  To that point, one can't really control how someone interacts with a post like this; I could only hope that they at least flag it for spam.  I'm merely giving advice with the best of intentions that they actually carry through and flag the bad question.  I would hope, now, that you would be doing the same.

Comment: @rene You're forgetting that the implicit downvote from a spam flag does not count as a user's downvote. There are a *lot* of users who will flag as spam *and* downvote, which actually leaves 2 downvotes on the post, from one spam flag. The number of users who downvoted but didn't flag is probably much lower than you're theorizing.

Comment: @rene But if you arrive at a post that has 6 downvotes, it could very well have been 3 users flagging as spam *and* downvoting. You can't assume it was just 6 people downvoting and not flagging. (Note I'm talking in general.)