# What is an OP when referring to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, terminology

When I hear OP, initially I think administrator or moderator, but it seems like an OP is related to the person asking the question? What is OP an acronym  for?

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79804/175248

Comment: If this was [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tour), this question would closed as a duplicate of *[Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: That doesn't make a post off-topic. See [Meta hasn't changed at all](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251375)

Answer (score 337, accepted):

OP stands for *Original Poster*.

It is used to refer to the person asking the question, or sometimes, the author of the answer being commented on.

<sub>[Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420)</sub>

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the context? I also use it to mean "Original Post". Or am I an oddball for yet another reason?

Comment: It's sometimes used for original post, but original poster is far more common.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use "Asker" and "Answerer" instead. It is crystal clear and newbies don't have to cope with SO jargon as soon as they enter into this world. Imagine a question discussing operands, operators and Opcodes in programming world.

Comment: I agree with @RBT I've been on StackOverflow for a while and could kind of guess what it meant contextually after a long while, but alas was chased here to find out for sure. Sigh. (._.)

Comment: I agree with RBT. @RBT: for newbies, SO stands for "StackOverflow" ;- )

Answer (score 37):

It's a common term from bulletin boards, message boards, and suchlike. When someone starts a thread they are the OP (**O**riginal **P**oster) and their post is the OP (**O**riginal **P**ost). The term doesn't make as much sense for the Q&A format of Stack Exchange but it is similar enough that it got carried over.

Comment: This is more correct than Martijn's answer since it both (a) references the true history of the term (i.e. that it LOOOOONG predates the *existence* of StackOverflow - I remember seeing this term used on many, many BBS systems back in the days of dial-up modems and the BBS systems that existed for a handful of years before Tim Berners-Lee invented HTML/websites), and (b) provides both use cases, referencing both the poster *and* the post itself - one understood the meaning by context.