# Addressing people in comments

Tags: support, comment-replies

Can I address my comment to the user which not commented an appropriate question/answer using @- notation (I.e. @SomeUser, where SomeUser does not comment that answer/question)?

Comment: Gah... maybe community bumps should happen pending a grammar review.

Answer (score 2):

No. A comment notifications are limited to the OP, anyone that already commented, if there is a bounty, the bounty placer, if the post is closed by a community moderator, the moderator, and anyone that has edited the post.

See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for the full details.

Comment: What does OP mean?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: ['original poster'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253162/what-is-an-op-when-referring-to-stack-exchange/253163#253163)

Answer (score 2):

If the user edited your question/answer, then you can. Otherwise, you cannot.

Using the @-notation, you can mention

- people who commented to your question/answer.
- people who edited your question/answer.
- a ♦ moderator who closed your question.

Comment: *"...your question/answer..."* No matter whose question/answer it is. You can address commenters of any post. OP also didn't even mention *their/my* so why this confusing limitation in your answer?