# How should questions containing proprietary code be handled when OP asks for deletion

Tags: discussion

When a user asks for help without reading the FAQ first, and posts code that they are working with from their day job - how should the situation be handled when the OP requests that the code be taken down because it is proprietary?

[An example question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099966/combining-3-images-with-transparency/) resulted in the following (well up-voted) response:

> Code submitted on Stack Overflow and on Stack Exchange in general is not subject to your copyright. You have no right requesting it to be deleted. See the copyright at the footer of this page. Actually, you must give attribution to HamZa and to Stack Overflow if you are planning to use this code in your product.

This *is entirely true* - OP of course has no right to demand code be removed as it was his fault it was posted on StackOverflow and into the public domain in the first place. However, what if his job were on the line because he posted code he shouldn't have on StackOverflow without realising?

Is it "nope, that's it - bam". Is it entirely up to how well the user grovels for this? Of course it is entirely OP's fault, but I can't help but feel sorry for said person because they made a mistake and can't go back on it. I also can't help but feel this mistake may not be as uncommon as first thought.

What is the best way forward with things like this, or is it to be decided entirely on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: This was the first question on the [2014 SO moderator questionnaire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire). Might be worth reading through if you want the point of view of the new moderators and runnerups.

Comment: i thought OPs can always delete their own posts, can't they?

Comment: Nope @Michael. If there are positively scored answers, they can't.

Comment: I want to add a note as the owner of the answer: If I remember correctly the user has suggested an edit to remove the code. I rejected it because IMO if you asked for help on SO and you got your answer then the Q&A should remain for future visitors. Otherwise, I might as well start a paid support helpdesk. A solution for the asker is to not provide identical code but a replication of the problem. The OP could as well just change my code in production instead of asking me to remove it.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the situation here. There was a question from User A. User B posted an answer with code. **User A** is now asking for the *answer* to be removed as they are claiming copyright over the code. There is no propriety code involved here.

Comment: Ah, so OP is merely wanting to *legally own* the code that HamZa wrote...

Comment: That's not to say that we don't get requests from people who posted their code in haste and only realised after the event they posted rather more than they intended. Flags like these are handled on a case by case basis.

Comment: Well, it seems he claims it now **is** their code. Which it of course is not. It's @HamZa's. He still holds the copyright, but has licensed it under a CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: Surely if an answer provides code so specific to the situation that it could violate copyright or anything like that (regardless of CC license) then surely the question itself would be unsuited to the site as it's not a question of benefit to anyone other than the OP? (Not sure if that's the case here or not). I thought questions were meant to be of use to a wide variety of people. Solving general programming problems, not writing specific code for single, bespoke situations?

Comment: It takes a lot of audacity to claim the code is yours after asking someone to help you with your problem. http://i.imgur.com/gUVpJQd.jpg

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194686/is-it-ok-to-use-stack-overflow-to-ask-questions-about-a-proprietary-framework) [is a](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information) [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140847/how-should-you-ask-questions-that-involve-proprietary-data-code).

Comment: We don't have a "too localized" option any more, do we? ;)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Hence my attitude has gone from "poor guy, I don't want him to lose his job" to "you arrogant spoon" a little. Gosh, it's a roller-coaster of emotion this morning!

Comment: The question was also posted over a year ago, so it's something like closing the barn door after the horses are well over the horizon at this point.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have slightly misinterpreted what that comment says. What that comment actually means is

> *you cannot take code from Stack Overflow and then assert copyright to it **[unless it is yours to begin with]***.

The emphasis is mine. If you posted the code (and it was yours to begin with) then you own the copyright on it but you have granted StackExchange the rights afforded by the [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licence.

Generally code will not be removed unless you have a compelling reason - and it won't be removed by a ♦ moderator because they cannot change the revision history of an item. The removal has to be done by one of the Stack Exchange team whom you can get in contact with by using the *contact us* link at the bottom of the page.

Basically, the OP should never have posted proprietary code, most employment contracts have clauses about it. Arguably someone who is that careless has it coming - they may have cost their company considerably as the publishing could make it hard to patent the code or otherwise protect it.

Another reason why deletion requests are considered carefully and seldom granted is because most of them come from people who have posted assignment or homework code and don't want to get caught out by their professors, people will go to all sorts of lengths and claim all sorts of things to get their request granted.

So in summary:

- outright deletion requests are considered on a case by case basis by the SE team (usually the Community Manager responsible for that site)
- it has to be a compelling reason to have the request granted
- moderators do not have the power to fully nuke a question or answer
- deletion can be quite unfair on the members who took the time to provide assistance

Related:

- [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117)
- [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86202) to *Who has the privilege to delete a revision?*
- [Ability for mods to hard-delete a question or revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111754/146015)
- [answer from Community Manager Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155331/146015) talking about deleting content (although he was just a lowly mod when he wrote that answer)

Comment: Sometimes, I feel like I should be posting this every day: https://twitter.com/bradlarson/status/410442895842217984 . I've learned to take every deletion request involving "proprietary code" with a grain of salt, because almost all of them look to be students trying to cover up for their cheating or people trying to hide the fact that they got SO to do their work from their bosses or clients. The same lame excuses get used over and over again.

Comment: Heh. If it comes to it and the owner of the code is serious, then the owner (that is the employer, not the person who posted it) could issue SO a DMCA take-down notice. AFAIK the legal fact is that SO has no right to distribute it, because the person who posted it had no legal ability to grant the necessary CC license. No more than SO would have a license to distributed a ripped-off movie should I somehow manage to upload one to the site. That should separate the serious from the frivolous.

Answer (score 6):

This is an entirely legal question. If a user posts code that is not her or his IP (because it is the property of his or her employer), and to which the user has no legal right to grant the CC license, that the team would be very poorly advised to refuse a polite takedown request.

Answer (score 4):

**THIS IS NOT LEGAL ADVICE**

If I post copyright code to SO when I am not allowed to, then it's about me as the OP breaking some law. Great answers or not. Does not change the license the original code is under.

But I'm wondering if the modifications done by the people answering fall under the same license or the SO license. I would think that they fall under the SO license.