# How to handle users deleting their questions after receiving an answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I recently contributed an (seemingly correct) answer to [this question (10k+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247910/how-to-run-html-code-through-bookmarklet/24247984#24247984) which the user has now deleted.

The user recieved an answer in both the comments section as well as the formal answer section, which both detailed the same code and were both correct, **and** potentially useful to future visitors.

I have cast a vote to un-delete the question, but I am wary that the question itself is now permanently "cast away", as (to my knowledge) there doesn't exist any queue of questions being voted to be "un-deleted" in the same way we have close/re-open vote queues.

What is the process by which a question would be un-deleted?

Comment: Flag the post for moderator attention in a custom flag, and explain the problem.

Comment: I thought the questioner couldn't delete it if it has answers.

Comment: @Barmar I think that only applies to questions containing answers with *upvotes*. Mine had a downvote (which I am still confused about, but that's an entirely different matter) before the question was deleted. (Also, for reference, the question was recently deleted **again** by the user.)

Comment: I just cast the final undelete vote, and also upvoted your answer.

Comment: **Off-topic:** About the downvote (not me but I typically would), link-only answers aren't of very high quality and often get downvoted. Even when it's something simple, some explanation and/or appropriate doc links are possible. Though, if I downvote for that reason I typically leave a comment and reverse the dv if an explanation of code is given in a decent amount of time (thought not always to a high rep user).

Comment: @codeMagic Interesting... I can understand links and how they are counter-intuitive, but you would even downvote a (working) code snippet?

Comment: I meant code-only instead of link-only (but I would dv either) which I'm sure you figured out. I would (and do but didn't in this case) dv a working code snippet if it did not give any explanation whatsoever.

Comment: @codeMagic OK, fair enough.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok, how about if I don't have 10k rep, how can I flag it?

Comment: @Braiam One thing I've done before is flag one of the user's other posts, (as "other" explaining the situation)

Comment: As your answer was a one-line code snippet copied from someone else's comment, I'd leave it alone.  Worry about good answers instead.

Comment: @DonRoby I **did not** copy the comment, my post was made before the comment.

Comment: Sorry.  The timestamps don't make that clear.  Can't conceive why anyone would copy an answer to a comment, but I guess it happens.

Comment: So I was the one who asked and deleted the question. The reason I deleted it was because it was a small portion of code from a private company web-app, and although I had edited out some information, I felt that I left too much in and wasn't comfortable leaving it online associated with my username, which is associated with my identity. I understand why you'd want to keep it online, so I've since edited the question (and answer) to remove more information, but that's still accessible to those who view the edit history. Anyway, just thought I'd explain.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The primary goal of Stack Overflow is not to help the question-asker, but to create a repository of high-quality Q&A. If the OP deletes the question immediately after receiving an answer, they're simply being selfish, and thereby wasting the time of the people who took the time to read and answer it.

If it was a good question that's potentially useful to future visitors, then you can flag the question for moderator attention, and explain the situation using "Other" reason. If the question is bad, and too-localized, let it remain deleted. You shouldn't have answered it in the first place.

Deleting questions immediately after posting it is a good factor that count towards question-bans; if the OP continues to do this, the system will automatically detect this, and restrict them from asking new questions.

Comment: As I explained above, the reason I deleted it was because it was a small portion of code from a private company web-app, and although I had edited out some information, I felt that I left too much in and wasn't comfortable leaving it online associated with my username, which is associated with my identity. I understand why you'd want to keep it online, so I've since edited the question (and answer) to remove more information, but that's still accessible to those who view the edit history. Anyway, just thought I'd explain.

Comment: @crclayton That is **not** a good reason for deleting a question. See for exaple this [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254493/how-should-questions-containing-proprietary-code-be-handled-when-op-asks-for-del) on meta. Bottom line: just *don't* post proprietary/private code, because it wont simply be nuked away when you receive an answer. Also deleting a question is useless since everybody with 10k reputation can still see the question and its full history.

Comment: @crclayton: If you weren't comfortable with that information being associated with your Stack Overflow account, you shouldn't have posted the question in the first place. Once you hit that "Submit" button, you're giving Stack Exchange full rights to host that content, *forever*. So you should be very careful to not accidentally publish any proprietary code/sensitive information. (In extreme cases, you could [contact Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) directly and request the developers to delete that revision though.)

Comment: This begs the question : shouldn't there be a way to remove your username from your post?

Comment: @PieterB: No; why should there be? If you don't want others to see your username, don't post it. As simple as that.

Comment: @Amal Murali I agree, I just made a mistake and I didn't think it would explode into this meta post w/ 500 views. But I disagree with your reasoning, you're essentially saying that I shouldn't have deleted the question because I shouldn't have asked the question in the first place, that doesn't really have anything to do with why I deleted it.

Comment: @Bakuriu, my last comment was actually in response to you, not Amal Murali.

Answer (score 7):

After watching this scenario play out multiple times, User asks question, waits until he gets the answer he wants, and then for whatever reason, (i.e. to prevent classmates from getting answer, prevent teacher from discovering the assistance, etc..) deletes the question moments after having copied and pasted a local copy on his machine. For all the reasons given, this wastes the efforts of those good enough to try and help, and denies all future questioners the benefit of the answer.

To prevent this gaming of SO and robbing all other/future users the benefit of the answer, I would propose that a user not be able to delete their post (in addition to the current limit imposed by upvote of an answer, etc..) if the question itself has not received downvotes.

While there is no reason to force a questioner to maintain a question that is getting hammered by downvotes, preventing a question from being deleted where there are no downvotes insures that valid questions/answers are not being lost for dubious reasons. It will also quickly dissuade posting by those who intend to delete and conceal the help they get here if they know there is a real possibility they cannot delete what they post.

As part of this scheme **close** and other actions should not count as downvotes on the question, thereby allowing deletion. Only a downvote of the question itself should enable the ability to delete for the questioner. (Lord knows that is a small hurdle for bad questions to get over here)

The basic scheme should be something along the lines of:

```
del disabled if (Quest Value >=0 || any Ans Value > 0 || any current checks)
```

This would preserve the useful questions, and the hard work of those providing answers, from being deleted by someone looking to game the system for personal gain. It would also serve as a bit of justice in the event the questioner was misusing SO intending to delete so his assistance could not be found out.

While this (get answer and delete) has been very noticeable this past week or so, I guess it goes along with the end of the semester. SO does a pretty darn good job in all areas, but this is one where a tweak is needed.

Comment: I request a change on this proposal: when the delete button is clicked, the "ah ah ah! You didn't say the magic word!" videoclip from Jurrasic Park is displayed.