# User who continuously deletes questions after getting an answer, then posts a followup

Tags: discussion, etiquette, help-vampire

I think I spotted some bad behavior by an Stack Overflow member: he asks a question, then gets an answer, and then deletes the first question and asks a more narrow question. He'll delete the new one too after getting an answer, so that little by little he gets spoon fed, while never giving any credit, nor leaving any information/knowledge for others.

I feel this behavior is just disrespectful to the community, but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: The user will be banned after a few iterations of that.

Comment: But how could that be spotted ? After all a user might delete questions for good reasons ?

Comment: The ban is automatic. The system will catch it. No human needs to do anything. If the "good reason" is to hide something from a professor or an employer, that's not really a good reason at all.

Comment: Well my 20 to 1 bet is that the user i'm thinking about is doing just that and wasn't spotted. That's what my question is about maybe : what to do in such a case.

Comment: Just flag a moderator.

Comment: Flag one of the poster's questions with a custom flag, and explain what you think you've spotted. A moderator can look into the issue.

Comment: The right answer would be to undelete the question/answers then ban the user. So the trick is exposed and more importantly some knowledge returns back to the community. Possible ?

Comment: see also: [How to handle users deleting their questions after receiving an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260692/how-to-handle-users-deleting-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer)

Answer (score 43):

In all honesty, they're only hurting themselves with this sort of behavior.  The system will catch them and dispense some indiscriminate justice.

However, [since a question can't be deleted by the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/175248) if there's at least one upvoted answer, if there's a pattern of this and you see a relatively good answer on the question, then upvoting it would actually put a halt to it.  This way, we at least save the valuable answers on the question.

Comment: Somehow, I suspect that the questions posted by someone who behaves in this way (and by extension, any answers people give to them) have little or no value anyway.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many pearls you could find amongst the sand, @MarkAmery.

Comment: Which then would dictate that we need more sand, right? ;)