# What to do if an error is made in the reason provided when a post is marked for moderator intervention?

Tags: discussion, flags

The story is as follows:

This post: [How to disable the default copy/paste behavior in QTreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52332885/5366641) was deleted by its author *after* the OP managed to find the issue thanks to the examples I have provided in my well thought and written with much effort [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52334648/5366641).

The effort was required, because of the lack of MCVE I've had to test a couple of scenarios to come up with a meaningful and helpful answer and I truly believe that deleting the question instead of giving the necessary credit is not the correct behavior and should not be encouraged.

So, I have flagged the question for moderator attention, describing the situation pretty much as I do it here.

**The problem is:** I have missed the `not`s in my last sentence, i.e.

> is  the correct behavior and should be encouraged.

This changes the meaning and probably makes it doubtful what I wanted to say.

What is the correct action at this point and what is the correct one for such cases in general (I am asking about the error in the reason description)?

As for the deletion itself, I have read about [User who continuously deletes questions after getting an answer, then posts a followup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272202/5366641), but first, it does not provide an answer for my case and second, it is not what I am asking about here.

Comment: Can't you retract your flag?

Comment: @rene, Would I be able to raise another one? I mean the same type.

Comment: Yes, I just tested that on this question ....

Comment: I had 7 seconds of time to decline the flag ... @rene ... you gotta be faster

Comment: *mumble lurking mods mumble go suspend some users mumble*

Comment: @rene, it works. :) From what I have tried up to now I was left with the impression, that one type of flag could be raised only once and retracting it does not allow for it to be raised again. Thank you for your help! I have learned something.

Comment: @rene like users who abuse the mod flag queue for testing purposes? ;)

Comment: That specific flag looks like any moderator would overlook that error easily... it's fairly obvious what you meant just based on the rest of the text.

Comment: Next time you may want to prevent yourself from wasting time answering questions from people that cannot even be bothered to post a MCVE

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can retract a flag while it is not yet handled.

That will allow you to re-raise the flag, hopefully with the correct information this time.

Do note that self-removed flags still show up in your flag history

[image]

And if you have a lurking moderator you might have only little time to correct your mistake.

If your flag is already handled, you can raise it again, assuming the mistake you made caused incorrect assessment of your flag. Don't keep re-raising a flag because you disagree with the moderator ruling, come to meta in that case.