# I flagged a question when it was deleted after receiving an answer, the flag is still pending 5 days later, is there anything else I can do?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, custom-flags

This question:

[QString replace characters outside of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399753/qstring-replace-characters-outside-of-quotes)

was removed by its author 4 minutes after a working solution has been proposed by me. This is enough time to copy the code, having in mind that the OP was active at that time and answered my attempts to clarify the question in the comments section.

The OP's account has been removed too.

I have put enough effort to come up with a decent solution quickly. Instead of giving an attribution for helping him/her, the OP removed the question.

I do not think this is a fair behavior, which should be encouraged. That is why I have flagged the question for moderator intervention, describing the situation and asking to undelete the post.

However, I am not sure if this is the right way to bring the question (and my answer) back, since I was in a similar situation recently with this post:

[How to disable the default copy/paste behavior in QTreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332885/how-to-disable-the-default-copy-paste-behavior-in-qtreeview)

and I have flagged it for moderator intervention as well. However, it has been already some time (5 days at the moment of this post), but the flag is still `pending`.

I understand that the moderators have a lot to do. That is why I am asking this question. Probably there is a way for the community to solve this, which I am not aware of.

So, as it is not a very rare event, probably it would be a good idea to know:

What should I do in such situations?

## References

- I have read about [User who continuously deletes questions after getting an answer, then posts a followup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272202/user-who-continuously-deletes-questions-after-getting-an-answer-then-posts-a-fo), but it does not provide an answer for my case.
- Here is a related discussion initiated by me about the moderator intervention flag:

  [What to do if an error is made in the reason provided when a post is marked for moderator intervention?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374123/what-to-do-if-an-error-is-made-in-the-reason-provided-when-a-post-is-marked-for)

Comment: Mod flags can take some time (few mods, lots of users flagging stuff). They'll get to yours, eventually. Sadly they waste some time eating and sleeping, which impedes us from getting peak mod efficiency.

Comment: @yivi, I understand that the moderators have a lot to do. That is why I am asking what is the proper action. Probably there is a way for the community to solve this, which I am not aware of.

Comment: On that first question the OP deleted their account as well. It would be interesting to know if they can return with a new account and do this same trick

Comment: Well, there is, I voted to undelete.  But best for a mod to handle this.  Something else funky going on, the user account was deleted.  I think the earlier deletion was appropriate, the OP commented that his question was too misleading and the real issue was another one.

Comment: I susspect it was an exam or a homework and the OP didn't want to be caught. However, exam or not, the question has been asked and the answer received. Removing it is selfish.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you for your vote!

Comment: Yup... asking a question, getting an answer, deleting your Q and then self-deleting your account 12 seconds later isn't fair play and it smells of they intended to do that all along given the time frames between actions (and the fact self-deleting an account isn't exactly completely an obvious thing to do if you don't know it's there - people generally won't find it in 12 seconds or at all). It's undeleted now and the OP won't be able to do anything as they've left so no longer own the post.

Comment: On that second question the OP left a comment that they made a mistake that basically renders the question invalid. It seems a good reason to delete a question. That it takes your answer with it is unfortunate but if it is unlikely someone in the future will run into the issue the OP didn't have the question is better deleted and stays deleted. But I'm not an expert, YMMV.

Comment: @rene, the mistake becomes obvious after one looks at the example I have provided. So it is a fair to leave it.

Comment: @JonClements, thank you for the quick reaction!

Comment: @scopchanov as to your other flag (which I've marked helpful in this case but left the post as is) - moderators aren't likely to have domain knowledge to determine if the Q&A pair is useful and in that case a fairly well established user decided to retract their question as it wasn't what they asked (based on a comment) - unless you can get consensus from meta that the OPs decision to remove their Q should be overriden as the site's losing valuable content - then there's not much else we can do here.

Comment: @JonClements, may I ask you to clarify: _unless you can get consensus from meta_. Do you mean the current post, or another action is required by me?

Comment: Sure... What I mean is on the first one - it's great - it's a clear hit and run, mods can undelete that and it's useful for us to have a record to keep an eye out for similar things from the same user if they hang around. In the second case, the OP's entitled to delete their question and we're not going to unilaterally overrule that. That's the sort of thing you can raise on meta (instead of flagging) so that the domain knowledge experts and even the OP themselves can discuss and reach a conclusion/resolution of whether it should remain deleted/edited or undeleted etc...

Comment: @JonClements, if I understand correctly, this is the right action. Please add this as an answer.

Comment: @JonClements, I have added more info to my question. I would appreciate if you could take a moment to consider it. Thank you once again for the help!

Comment: @scopchanov I'd put this question back how it was so it covers the base of "what should I do when ... happens"... Then, as I said in my comment, you could write a new meta post to open discussion specifically on the pros/cons of the 2nd Q/A you linked and whether it should be undeleted or not. Having said that - the general view in the comments here is that it should remain deleted - so you'll have to consider if it's worth it. Don't forget if you really think it's information that's lost - you can always repost your own Q with a self answer.

Comment: @JonClements, _repost your own Q with a self answer_ seem better to me as _write a new meta post_. I will take this advice. Thank you for your time and explainations!

Comment: @JonClements, all prescriptions are followed: the question is reverted and the knowledge is shared: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403771/how-to-disable-the-default-copy-behavior-in-qtreeview. Your guidance was helpful to me. Would you mind to summarize this in an answer, which I could accept?

Comment: @Luuklag, I have updated the question with more specifics, about how it is different from the mentioned one.

Comment: @yivi, you are right about all what you've said. I just want to point your attention also to what JonClements suggested about reposting it as a self answered Q/A, which I eventually did.

Comment: I wouldn't give too much emphasis to the "repost the question" angle. That is only true if for some reason the mods decline your flag, and you can still re-post the question with enough modifications to make it a valid, on-topic question (so, not very often). The general rule is: **Q**: _what to do when this happens?_ **A**: _Flag for mods and wait._

Comment: @yivi, you are right, of course. And because I am a fan of making _enough modifications to make it a valid, on-topic question_ (not only in this, but also in other cases when I think I am able to salvage the post) so for me this is a better solution **if** the person in this situation is willing to do it, as I am in example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's unsporting type of behaviour. Post a question, get the answer, delete and run. I often suspect people are asking for homework assignments or even sitting in exams when that happens and don't want to be caught.

What do to do?

### Raise a mod flag and be patient.

Emphasis on the ***be patient*** :)

Apart from raising a mod flag or posting on meta, which will get mod or community manager attention, there's nothing the actually community can do.

#### Why is it taking so long to handle flags?

Two reasons it's taking so long to get through all the custom mod flags.

1. People not knowing when to use a custom mod flag. Don't use a custom mod flag if a standard flag will satisfactorily cover the reason for flagging.

[Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368693/why-was-my-custom-flag-declined-when-should-i-use-a-custom-flag)

2. A rise in comment flags.

[Can we have some statistics on the potential change in rate of comment flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313872/can-we-have-some-statistics-on-the-potential-change-in-rate-of-comment-flags)

The rise in the unkind flags takes mods more time to handle, as it can take more effort to understand a flagger and a commenters perspective to understand whether or not a flag is actually unfriendly and with that there is a penalty on the user that then raises another mod flag warning of too many abusive comments.. As mentioned, if in doubt flag it as no longer needed.

[When is a comment hostile or unfriendly? (Educating newer users how to flag comments)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm)

So again a plea for sanity with comment flagging:

[Comments asking for clarification or an MCVE are not rude/abusive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368072/comments-asking-for-clarification-or-an-mcve-are-not-rude-abusive)

Also noteworthy.  A user cannot delete a question with an upvoted answer.

Comment: Your answer is more complete and through than the one in the dupe target that I proposed. Maybe you could close **that one** as a dupe to this one?

Comment: Or maybe adding your answer to that one is better?

Comment: @yivi yes I was looking at that. I have a vested interest. You can vote the dupes the other way around. I'll ping a mod and ask.

Comment: If you add your answer to that other question, no need to reverse the dupe direction, though. Right?

Comment: @yivi true. I'm also enjoying this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317470/what-can-i-do-if-a-user-removes-a-question-after-ive-written-an-extended-answer Not sure what to do tbh. I don't want to post duplicate answers. There is the added conundrum that in this case the OP did flag and was wondering what to do, as the flag was pending

Comment: Although to be fair, that's a different question. It is nice that you address it, and part of the reason I like your answer more than the other one, but the main question is exactly the same and has exactly the same answer, IMO.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it gives an in-depth view of how the flagging works, which might seem like a departure from the topic at a first glance, but it actually helps understand that matter better.

Comment: @scopchanov I was going to suggest changing the title along the lines of "I flagged a question when is was deleted after receiving an answer, the flag is still pending 5 days later, is there anything else I can do?"

Comment: @YvetteColomb, done. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @scopchanov I'm asking some other users if they think it's still a dupe. I'd rather not unilaterally make that decision

Answer (score 11):

It's unfortunate when this happens.

Usually users do this because they don't want it to be known that they recieved help from stack overflow. Sometimes this is because the question is from a test or skill asessment, sometimes this is because they think their employer might react negatively towards it.

In these cases, all you can do is flag for a moderator to undelete the question. This can be done with a custom "needs moderator intervention" flag on any post (your answer or the question would be most pertinent). Make sure to explain yourself thoroughly so the moderators will be aware of exactly what happened.

Depending on the time of day and general moderator workloads, this may take a few days to resolve. Sometimes moderators also may not undelete the question.

Comment: don't forget if the flag is reviewed and the mod thinks the post shouldn't be undeleted they will decline the flag. So it wouldn't be pending. (I know you know this, just making a note for other readers)