# Why does the moderator intervention flag bears a pending status even when the respective answer is deleted?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-answer, moderator-intervention

As the *in need of moderator intervention* flag mentions that *flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention* then is there any other reason for the *moderator intervention* flag being in pending status even when the respective answer is deleted?

The relevant discussion is [Is it possible to do screenshots in Selenium java? s [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846568/is-it-possible-to-do-screenshots-in-selenium-java-s/53846636#53846636)

Snapshot of the deleted answer for users < 10K rep users:

[image: mod_flag_active_answer]

Snapshot of pending status:

[image: pending]

I have been through this discussion [I flagged a question when it was deleted after receiving an answer, the flag is still pending 5 days later, is there anything else I can do? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/i-flagged-a-question-when-it-was-deleted-after-receiving-an-answer-the-flag-is) but it was about the question and not related to the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The author deleted their own answer. We haven't had a chance to review the flag or intervene yet, so your flag remains pending to give us that chance to look at it.

If the problem has resolved itself we'll simply dismiss your flag as helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but just like _NAA_ and _VLQ_, shouldn't the answer be discarded from the _Moderators Queue_ once deleted by the author. Won't that lesser the volume for the moderators? I clearly don't see any value addition for the moderators reviewing a deleted answer.

Comment: @DebanjanB: No because there's the possibility that the flag is trying to bring some other issue to our attention that's unrelated to the quality of the answer (hence why it's a custom, moderator-attention flag). We don't want that kind of flag disappearing just by the author deleting their answer.

Comment: @DebanjanB If you feel your flag has no value since the q/a has been deleted, you can retract it yourself, btw. Don't know if that's possible for users that have <10K rep so can't see deleted posts though.

Answer (score 2):

@BoltClock's answer definitely pointed us to the right direction that *moderators haven't had a chance to review the flag or intervene yet, so your flag remains pending to give us that chance to look at it*. He also mentioned *if the problem has resolved itself we'll simply dismiss your flag as helpful.*.

Perhaps there are more chevet to this as the previous *author deleted their own answer* (snapshot below):

[image: mod_flag_active_answer]

Have now turned out as *moderator deleted the answer* with the several other clauses `comments disabled on deleted` / `locked posts` / `reviews` (snapshot below)

[image: mod_deleted]

Not sure of all the possible reasons. But one strong reason can be, as the answer earlier was self deleted by the author, so once the discussion goes out of focus, author could have **undeleted** this answer.

Kudos to StackOverflow for implementing this logic.