# How should we handle edits adding unnecessary inline `code` formatting?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code-formatting

I've seen a few (more than a few, no links at the moment) `suggested edits` where the user simply wants to add `code` tags as they believe `code` is needed for every proper noun on `Stack Overflow`. The `source` is not otherwise `improved`. Should I `reject`? I have been using `too minor` so far.

Comment: Yes. Reject as invalid, or too minor, if the edit doesn't fix other glaring faults as well. In that case, you can improve (and remove the offending code tags) if you have the willpower to do so.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back

Comment: @BoltClock Ah yes, the classic.

Comment: Wasn't there a back ticks question only last week?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/692942

Comment: @Lankymart: Indeed. This one's a bit different though - it's asking what to do with edits that don't use them according to the guidelines stated there.

Comment: I usually reject with a custom message along the lines of "Please use code formatting for code only".

Comment: @Lundin: Only problem is that many of these editors actually think what they're formatting is, in fact, code.

Comment: Reject surely. If it doesn't fit into any of the exceptions in that link then it should be rejected.

Comment: I feel I sometimes use them too often in my questions. Does anybody have the link to the guidelines so I can look when I should use them?

Comment: @Tom Hart: Lankymart's comment links to it.

Comment: I think the wording "tags" is a little confusing, if you mean inline code formatting.

Comment: @Scratte agreed and title edited.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`Answer` is

## YES you should `reject`

them...

I prefer `invalid edit` over `too minor` because that's `precisely` what they are: `invalid`. If anything, I `consider` littering a `post` with misused `code formatting` a `major` edit, almost bordering on `vandalism`.

Actually, I `think` I'm going to `start rejecting` these `edits` as `vandalism` from now on. `Here` is the `description` of the `vandalism` rejection option `(emphasis mine)`:

> This edit introduces spam, *`defaces the post in some way`*, or is otherwise inappropriate.

Comment: `vandalism`, YES!

Comment: I have to step away from the computer for some time; I'll accept once I'm back as the timer isn't up yet

Comment: @hexafraction: No worries, take as much time as you need - I understand if the formatting abuse is getting too much for you ;)

Comment: Must...resist...subconscious urge to downvote...

Comment: @BoltClock I resisted the urge to edit your answer sooo bad! It's actually painful to look at...

Comment: These kind of edits unfortunately gets accepted very often. I try to rollback such passed edits when I see them.

Comment: @Lundin: Oh you have no idea how familiar I am with such edits. See the link in my comment on the question.

Comment: I've always rejected them as vandalism. That's what they are.

Comment: Ah Bolt, your humor is subtle and in your face at the same time.  Very enjoyable.

Answer (score 18):

## `KILL` `IT` `WITH` `FIRE`!

[image: KILL IT!11]

Answer (score 5):

I will use back ticks for keywords that are a core technical component of a post, like a library name or technical elements in use ([see here where I wrap `push/pull` and `req/rep` to attempt to make it clear that I'm referring to ZMQ socket type pairs rather than general messaging strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23936106/545332)).  I'm getting the impression from the answers and comments that even this is frowned upon.  But I do agree that it's sometimes rather egregiously used in edits for almost any proper noun, and I otherwise like the accepted answer to reject.

I just see the line between valid and invalid to cover core technical concepts inherent in the text rather than just code.

Comment: It matters whether it's a code keyword or a key phrase in the discussion.  The latter shouldn't be formatted as code.  (You correctly wrote 'ZMQ' without code formatting)