# Should my suggested edit have been approved or rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Recently I [suggested this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4946617) based upon [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964345/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-middle-value-of-two-numbers#comment36920764_23964345) left by the question's author. Essentially, the OP had listed out some numerical values but had inserted a space between the minus sign and the number, so it had been formatted as a bullet point instead of what it really was. I felt that this was something that *should* be corrected as evidenced by the confusion in some of the other comments.

Now, I do care about the SO community (I only signed up a few months ago but I've lurked for a few years), and I like to ensure that I'm actually making beneficial contributions to it. I've noted that during the peer review two of the reviewers rejected the edit as too minor, and I would like to understand why so that I can improve my editing habits going forward. Was there something else that I should have changed in the post that I didn't?

I was torn over removing the "lol" from the question, in the end I felt that it would have seemed somewhat petty to get rid of it so I left it as it was.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your suggested edit. OP confirmed that numbers were wrong due to formatting. The question would be [confusing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964345/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-middle-value-of-two-numbers#comment36920719_23964345) without your edit. I don't see the point in rejecting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like some people don’t always pay enough attention when approving suggested edits, there are times when reject votes are cast mistakenly. This is one of those; don’t worry about it.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks for the reassurance there!

Answer (score 3):

To add on to [false's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256829/366904), I agree that this is a case of reviewers not paying enough attention. But the issue here is somewhat more complicated than that.

From a casual glance, it looks like you're doing the [horrible, evil, disgusting thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back) that so many editors have been doing recently: [adding inline code formatting to "accent" things that are not code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256333/how-should-we-handle-edits-adding-unnecessary-code-tags). It is really not necessary that these values be formatted as code, for they are *not* code. They also don't need to line up in any kind of fixed-width tabular format. A bulleted list is really the most appropriate presentation, it seems to me.

Rather, the issue was with how the markdown parser was interpreting the negative sign as a bullet point. You could (and arguably should) have fixed this by adjusting the markdown, keeping the bulleted list, but displaying a negative number. Like [I've done here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23964345/revisions).

Granted, you did provide an *excellent* edit summary that should have avoided this misunderstanding. I wish everyone would do what you did, it would make our job as reviewers much easier. Alas, they don't, leaving reviewers to make a lot of assumptions based on our experience—a largely negative body of experience that causes us to become rather jaded.

Keep on doing what you are doing, it is good work. But next time, definitely remove that "lol". And "hi". And "kthxbai". And any other noise that might show up. There's no reason for that to be left behind.

Notice that in [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23964345/revisions), I not only took out the "lol", but also removed the reference to his "tired, inebriated brain". Some might consider such a reference inappropriate, but all can agree it is "too chatty" and adds nothing important to the question. There also seems to be a strong community consensus that it is unnecessary for titles to be in the form of a question—and often clearer and more concise if they are not. So I made a simple change to the title as well. Finally, I fixed the grammar of the last sentence, and added a reiteration of the question (since that's the last thing the reader sees, I think that's the most appropriate way to conclude). I'm not saying that you have to edit exactly like I did, but there's no way anyone would have perceived mine as "too minor".

Comment: Funnily enough, I had actually formatted it as a bulleted list using asterisks for the markup at first, but then changed it before submitting it. As it was originally entered, it looked like the author intended for them to be on separate lines rather than a bulleted list, and the easiest way I could think to achieve that was to indent it as code and disable the syntax highlighting for it. Thank you for the insightful feedback - I will bear it in mind when I make edits in the future!