# Need clarification for a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion

I had made an edit to an existing post to correct one of the URL's used in the post, to the correct entry.
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5590835
The edit has been `rejected` with the following status:
`This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.`

I fail to understand how this edit is wrong.
[image: Rejected Edit]

This was the original `URL` specified:

[image: Original URL]

And this is the correct `URL` I specified:
[image: Edited URL]

Please tell me if any further information needs to be provided for this to make sense. To me it looks like that the people who handled the edit, either didn't know what they were doing, or it was due to a reason that I don't know. Anyhow it would be nice, if somehow helps me understand the reasoning behind this `reject`.

Comment: OT: as this post shows -- some of your edits do as well! --, you are using `code ticks` for just about everything slightly *related* to `code`. [Please don't.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256643/2564301)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better suggested edit would have copy/pasted the relevant code in the links to the answer, rather than trying to fix GitHub line number links which can change over time.  The Laravel software has a permissive license (MIT), and the small amount of code involved likely falls under Fair Use doctrine anyway.

Note that the links had [been fixed once already](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16597530/4).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the better alternative, now it makes sense. :)