# Should I format small code portions inside sentences as code? Why do people edit my posts this way?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I've seen several edits to my posts where people add small code formatting portions inline with non-code text. By small I mean between one to three words. The edited formatted words will be in non-code text in which I'm refer to something in a larger portion of code in the post, appropriately formatted. So if I post with code and then talk about a function() in it, someone will come by and change the sentence to talk about a `function()` in it.

This doesn't bother me but it seems odd and makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong by not code formatting every single word that might be code. I tend not to like the look of `every` other `word` formatted as code but mostly I'm indifferent.

Should I format everything that might be code as code? Is there some secret non-aesthetic reason for doing this? Does it provide hints to some script that scans my posts? Are these people just grabbing easy rep?

Comment: Yes, definitely you should do this. It enhances readability a lot! (I won't grab any rep on this, though would edit your post, if I find worth it)

Comment: Oh, it doesn't give rep? I thought approved edits did.

Comment: I think they meant rather that they did not want to post an answer to collect reputation. Yes, approved edits give you reputation, but if you gain the privilege to edit without going through the queue you don’t get reputation any more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So if I post with code and then talk about a function() in it, someone will come by and change the sentence to talk about a `function()` in it.

But that *is* code text. `function()` refers to either a function called `function`, or an invocation of said function. Either way, that looks like a code reference to me, which is fine.

Non-code `text` would be `something` like `this`, which it would `definitely` be `inappropriate` to `format` as `code`.

> Should I format everything that might be code as code?

You don't have to. But someone else might, and whether that is OK depends on whether or not they are doing it correctly. If it's wrong, you have every right to reject it or roll it back.

> Is there some secret non-aesthetic reason for doing this?

You know, I've always wondered the same thing about people who do this with text that decidedly *isn't* code. I've even tried asking, but never got an answer. As for why we do it to highlight text that *is* code...

> Does it provide hints to some script that scans my posts?

Not really, but it does wrap code spans in `<code>` tags, which could mean something to some screen reader. Although with the amount of misuse of code tags going on, I'm not sure how useful it really is.

> Are these people just grabbing easy rep?

Probably.

#### See also:

- [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)
- [How should we handle edits adding unnecessary `code` tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256333/how-should-we-handle-edits-adding-unnecessary-code-tags)