# Probable vote-up privilege bug on SO

Tags: support, voting, upvotes

I joined SO yesterday. I have 13 reputation (as of now when I an writing this post). Today, when I opened my account, it showed me **+12** on the *Achievements* tab.
[image]

I says that I have got the privilege of Voting Up. But I cannot vote-up questions when I tried to do so. Is this a bug?

Comment: Upvoting needs 15 rep, maybe you've been crossing the limit and an upvote was retracted later, or you've got downvoted.

Comment: I never posted a question or an answer. I just edited some posts. That's how I got the reputation.

Comment: You only need two more edits and then you can upvote post for real :-) It does seem strange though that it's telling you you can upvote even though you can't.. Maybe something you edited got deleted ?

Comment: @JonasCz Only one more edit, you get +2 per edit

Comment: One of the posts you edited got deleted by the OP. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34565477/revisions

Comment: Given that all your rep so far has come from suggested edits and you have no posts, there's no possible way that I know of (assuming that you haven't deleted a post) that you could've lost rep, and therefore no way that you could've lost a privilege. This does indeed seem to be a bug.

Comment: @Druzion I got it!

Comment: You have 1 rep when you join, you then earn 12 rep, you now have 13 rep. I don't understand what's so difficult about that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have wasted your time on editing a post that got [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565477/java-swing-error-when-getting-arraylist-from-different-class).

The reputation needs to add up based on still visible posts. If a post gets deleted reputation gained or lost by it will still affect your reputation. This may lead to the strange effect that your inbox has the message you gained a privilege while in reality you just dropped under it due to a post deletion or a down vote.

Reputation *will* stick after deletion if the post has 3 up votes and has been visible on the site for 60-days, as explained on this cross-site duplicate [Lost reputation on an edited question that was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145630/lost-reputation-on-an-edited-question-that-was-deleted) or this slightly older post [Do you lose your +2 edit rep if the edited post is subsequently deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted)

While I'm at it, please don't do back-ticks **only** edits. They might make the post a tiny bit easier to read but if that is all there is to be changed I personally wouldn't waste my time (and that of reviewers) on it. There are for sure other posts that can use your edit skills.

Comment: Do back-tick edits get sent to "Suggested Edits"?

Comment: Under 2k rep every edit you do is sent to the suggested edits queue where up to five users have to spend one of their twenty per-day review votes to reject or approve your suggested edit.

Comment: _"While we're at it, please don't do back-ticks only edits. They don't make the post much easier to read."_ I disagree.

Comment: Backtick edits make posts much, much easier for me to read. I am incredibly grateful for people who do them, and wish I could do them without being penalized. Is the only reason not to do them that they use up an artificially-limited resource, @TinyGiant ?

Comment: @jwg Backticks *may* make the post easier to read. But often you also see `random`ly distributed `backticks` for `word`s that are just `remotely` related to some `technical` term. But of course, in order to make clear which word is, for example, a `variableName` or so, they can be incredibly helpful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit made it clear that the `backticking` is my personal preference, not something that the community at large agrees with

Comment: @Marco That wasn't the `case` here.

Comment: @jwg No, the `biggest` reason not to do that is `because`, if used `incorrectly` like it most `commonly` is (as Marco mentions), it is just `formatting` noise that makes the post `harder` to read. Sure if you're going to put code in `back ticks`, go ahead (and `make sure` you fix any other `problems` the post may have while you're at it). See: [How `should` we handle `edits` adding `unnecessary` code tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256333)

Comment: @TinyGiant @Marco13 Surely we all agree that edits which are `incorrect` are a bad thing, regardless of whether they involve backticks or not?