# Is this really a harmful edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation, review-suspension

I have received a review ban for one year (after some review bans due to carelessness) and would like to ask this to be discussed and reviewed.

As far I can see I was banned because approving this edit [kinect scale skeleton to match reference skeleton](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16868299)

The editor/user 'Ali Majed HA' corrected an typo "downalod" and improved question formatting for better reading only. So, that is why I chose "Approved".

OK - the editor breaks a rule `inline code in backticks` - but in this case I have approved as an exception.

A moderator did a rollback to Revision 1, the corrected typo comes back and is still there and I'm banned for a year.

Is this really a harmful edit resulting in my ban as you can see in the link above?

I'd like ask the moderators to reset my review ban.

Comment: That's an *awful* edit. I hope the editor is getting some repercussions too. Two corrections vs. six instances of backtick BS (probably done because the system wouldn't accept the two corrections as too little).

Comment: In this case, IMO should have done reject - edit to fix the spelling issues..It wouldnt have taken much effort on your part

Comment: This is not a useful edit, and definitely not worthy of the 2 points that come with it.

Comment: A full year does seem a but harsh. I didn't know bans could stretch that far. But I don't make the rules.

Comment: @Pekka웃 This is also at least the third meta question this week by reviewers who got review banned because of approving the same kind of edits by the very same editor. Looking at their edit history it's unbelievable how many of their unacceptable edits have been approved. A few of them were cleaned up or rolled back by other editors but by far not all of them. Based on this it should be raining review bans for everybody who has ever accepted any of these edits and an edit ban for the editor who is wasting everybody's time with up to 20 low quality (accepted) edit per day.

Comment: *in this case I have approved as an exception.* Why would you make an exception here? First, there's no reason to make an exception with edits because we can make additional edits to suggestions (as suraj pointed out). Second, The only correct thing they did was fix a typo that was so small they wouldn't have been able to do it if it was the only edit made. They also ignored grammar errors and then uncapitalized a proper name.

Comment: This is a great example of how `Stack Overflow` standards have fallen so much over time. Instead of adding content to the site, especially for currently hot languages such as `Java`, `C#`, and `Python`, we are debating the fairness of a `ban` issued by a `Moderator`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First off, review bans are never handled out for a single failed review, so you obviously have made incorrect decisions on *multiple* reviews. This should all be visible to you in your review history, so representing it here to us as if that's the one review that caused you to fail seems a bit disingenuous to me.

Even more importantly, review bans are applied on a sliding scale, with the duration increasing each time one needs to be applied. So, the first ban would have been something like 3 or 7 days. The next ban would have been longer. You don't get up to a year-long ban unless you've *repeatedly* made incorrect reviews and have shown no indication that you've learned from your mistakes. [Here's an example of an audit that you had previously failed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14164059), and for which you were given a shorter ban.

Second, *yes*, that edit you approved is absolutely a harmful edit. All that edit does is add incorrect formatting (inline code formatting to words that are not code). I don't see any redeeming value in it other than a single typo correction, and that cannot make up for trashing the formatting and making the post unreadable. This isn't a borderline case where you could possibly have been thinking, *"Well, the formatting is incorrect, but the edit does other good things, so…"*.

**See also:**

- [How should we handle edits adding unnecessary `code` tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256333/how-should-we-handle-edits-adding-unnecessary-code-tags)
- [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)

Comment: Agreed - but, you know working in the review queues is a hard job to improve the site and to remove all the garbage. In the overall context, I consider the review ban for one year unjustified.

Comment: Yes, working through the review queues is a lot of drudgery, @help-info.de. However, making *bad* decisions in the review queues just creates more work for everyone, so we want to avoid that at all costs. When you approve bad edits, or say that low-quality questions are "ok", that just means someone else will have to go back and fix the damage. That's why review bans exist, and it's unfortunately what happened in this case. Remember that if you are ever unsure about a review, you can always click Skip! There's no shame in skipping things you're unsure about. Or asking for help.

Comment: It seem to me, successfully passed audits are not be included in the calculation of the review ban - and I passed many congratulation ...

Comment: Failed audits are weighed much more heavily, yes. The idea behind audits is that they are *very simple and obvious*, so if you fail them, you are either not paying attention or you don't understand what our quality standards are. You had been automatically banned from reviewing **11** times before this last ban, but they don't seem to have helped much. You were still approving terrible edits. As I said, this creates more work for everyone, so the ban got much longer this time. If you didn't understand why you were banned those previous times, you should have asked for help *then*. @help-info

Comment: @help-info.de wrongly accepted bad edits are bot included in the calculation as well and you seem to have several of those....