# Why is this kind of code formatting not acceptable in Suggested Edit review?

Tags: support, review-queues

I was recently suspended from the [Suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review) review queue. There were several "incorrectly handled" reviews that I understood that should be acceptable, but it turns out that it wasn't.

One of which is this https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33747960.

I thought (and still think) that formatting the text of plain code into a code block would more or less improve the post in terms of readability. In addition, the technical terms in the edit that was formatted into a code block, which I am still not sure if it is an improvement but I myself think that it does not destroy or change the intent of the words and its author. It feels like an emphasis of the technical terms to me. With that, I think the edit is a little plus to the question.

So, I would like to ask why this kind of code formatting is not acceptable in Suggested Edit review? I do not ask for a lift of the suspension. I just want to know what is the most proper way to handle this so that I can properly review next time.

Comment: But the editor forgot to format the code at the bottom, and no reviewer edited it.

Comment: @AndrewT. In my opinion, the edit is still an improvement. There is no need to reject part of the improvement even if you see that some other parts need to be edited. I could be wrong though.

Comment: This looks like a good place to reject so that the suggester sees: "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed." Or to improve the edit yourself if you see the part at the bottom with code not formatted as code. The suggested edit is definitely an *improvement*, but it's also incomplete...

Comment: @CertainPerformance According to the "Learn More" that links to "How to use the Suggested edits queue" dialog at the top left corner of the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33747960), there are several guidance but I will pick some to discuss. **Edits should maintain the post author’s original intent.** Yes, it is. **Reject edits that are spam, attempt to reply to the post author, or clearly worsen the post.** This clearly does not worsen the post. **Even small changes can be good edits! Choose Improve edit if a post could use more changes.** This can be a good edit.

Comment: @CertainPerformance [cont.] Another option that I think is more suitable is to choose Improve edit. However, the conclusion is "Reject", which comes back to my question. Why is it not acceptable?

Comment: I find this to be a rather nit-picky rejection. We need as many people reviewing as we can get, if we routinely shoot people down for not seeing additional opportunities to improve we're just pushing potential curators away.

Comment: Re *"the technical terms in the edit that was formatted into a code block"*: There is a meta question for that somewhere (probably many, many duplicates).

Comment: A starting point: *[How should we handle edits adding unnecessary inline `code` formatting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256333/how-should-we-handle-edits-adding-unnecessary-inline-code-formatting)*

Comment: Cross-site (2012): *[Inline code spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)*. For example: *"Is iOS a "computery" thing? Yes. Should it be a code span? No."*. There is also [the *accessibility* aspect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right/301372#301372).

Comment: As a Side Note, the added Capital on "*To turn*" is not correct in the "final Edit", and "*my prices has gone from...*" doesn't make sense grammatically (not corrected); correct would have been "*including the decimal**s** and now my price has gone from...*" (or "*my prices have gone from...*", but I think Singular would be better, as only 1 Example is included...)

Comment: tl;dr: the correct change is not "dataframe" to "`dataframe`"; it *could* be to "`DataFrame`", but it doesn't really need to be changed. Changing "int" to "`int`" is *okay*, but changing it to "integer" would be better most of the time - since the question is about the type on a conceptual level, not an implementation level.

Comment: @KevinB agreed; hence my plea to accept-and-improve things that are net positive.

Comment: @holydragon because the suggested edit was not complete you should have either clicked improve or reject, don't accept incomplete edits

Comment: It seems like ChatGPT has entered the [Suggested edits review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review). Now we see ***complete*** rewrites of entire paragraphs and of entire code blocks. It is like they prompt ChatGPT with *"ChatGPT, how can this paragraph be improved?"* or *"ChatGPT, how can this code be simplified?"*. [A sample](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33773473) (that is not the only one). It might be OK if they check the result ***thoroughly***, but the suspicion is that they don't.