# Why is the accepted answer not on top?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer, sorting

This question [Is there a way to get the count size for a JPA Named Query with a result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285270/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-count-size-for-a-jpa-named-query-with-a-result-set) has an accepted answer, but it is drowned pretty drowned in other answers - even though it has positive upvotes. Why is that?

Comment: It's at the top for me... Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: You're probably sorting by "active" or "oldest", not "votes".

Comment: I had to look, but I have default sorting (by active) as in any other question

Comment: Its same for me. It is showing after 2 answers with 0 and 1 upvotes.

Comment: I'm confused why 'active' is your default sorting for answers.  That's not the case for me (Votes).  Why wouldn't votes be the default sorting?  "Good answers rise to the top" only works when votes is your default sort ;)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212196/accepted-answer-not-on-top

Comment: Now that this is no longer relevant, should this question be closed? Accepted answers are no longer pinned to the top after the summer 2021 overhaul.

Comment: @tripleee I am ok with that, feel free to close it :)

Comment: I can't do that alone, but I have now voted to close as unreproducible.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It's self-answered and the asker accepted their own answer. In that case, we don't sort that answer to the top.

Comment: didnt know that, thanks for clarifying.. I do not see any meaningfull reason for that, as any accepted question (own or not) can be wrong or bad, so the only effect is that i dont see the "correct" answer as first... but i am sure this has beed discused and the decision is supported

Comment: @Zavael What about this: the Op asks a question, you answer it correctly. He downvotes you for no reason, and you point that out to him. Afterwards he posts *exactly the same answer as yours* and accepts its self answer. (real [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14547631/510937) happened to me) Normally answers that are basically copy/pasted are deleted since they only add noise.

Comment: @Bakuriu - yes I thought about this, but he can do that even now, if his answer remains at the position where it is... what will change that his answer will not be TOP-ed? and if something like this happens, the its likely that after pointing it out the community downwotes his answer so it will be at the top with dozen of minuses :) - public punishment

Comment: @Zavael We want the *good* answers to go on top. People often don't read past the first answer, even though it may be worse than other answers.

Comment: @Zavael It would be **really** meta if you copied this answer yourself and accepted it.

Comment: @Bakuriu ok, but there exists some presumption of innocence. You expect from the beginning that the users own answer is copied or bad or in other way not worth to be TOP-ed? :)

Comment: @SeñorO i dont understand the term "to be really meta":(

Comment: @Zavael If the OP answer is good it will be upvoted anyway and go on top (see all the awesome self-answered question by top users for example). So I really don't see any downside and this mechanism has the upside of handling the cases were the OP accepts the "wrong" answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu With this reasoning we don't need any acceptance priority in sorting of solutions at all since the good answers will be upvoted anyway.

Comment: @Bakariu I agree completely, we want good answers on top, and votes are meant to sort out good answers from less good answers. So why do we even put any accepted answer on top? Reasoning is exactly the same for self- and non-self-accepted answers. If it's good, it'll reach the top anyway.

Comment: Old answer, but how does this make sense? [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). The accepted self-answer has 49 up-votes. Yet a later answer with +1/-1 votes stick to top. There's also a deleted answer which appears higher up. This whole mechanism seems quite buggy to me.

Comment: Exactly as KPM wrote, either let the accepted answer be on top and other ordered by votes, or all order by votes and people will find the accepted one if the best is not enough. @Bakuriu It still can be reverse as the ban for self answering is trying to solve: I ask a question, nobody tries to help me, after learning more I am able to answer it and accept it, somebody copies it and will have a answer over mine and gets the upvotes from others instead of mine answer.

Answer (score 42):

It's not on top because it's a self-answer.

The only time an accepted answer doesn't stick to the top is when it's a self-answer. Then it's sorted as though it were any other answer.

Comment: in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371530/no-internet-on-openvpn-connection) at the time of writing there are multiple 0-voted answers, with one of them accepted. Since all answers are votewise equal, wouldn't it make sense for the accepted one be put on top by default? (I have sorting by votes). I can understand it wouldn't be on top if there are other answers that have more votes, but given equal vote count, I don't understand the reasoning of treating it as equal.