# Editing self-answer out of question

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

[This self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4604486/1928529) contains the answer in the question body. In this way it shows the easiest (and probably the best) way of solving the problem in a highly visible place. At the moment this is helpful as [the answer with the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767348/1928529) is buried under a few older answers. Should this self-answer get edited out nonetheless? Should this happen when the answer with the same information is upvoted to the top? Or should I/we just leave it as it is?

Comment: It is too old and has too many answers.  If you edit it out of the question then it will disappear out of sight at the bottom.  Maybe future visitors can fix that but I'd say leave it.

Comment: As a compromise, it could be edited to say "this question only applies to git < 1.8.5, because.."

Comment: @HansPassant I first added a comment to the question with a link to the answer, a link to the release notes, and the command that was shown in the self-answer. After that my suggested edit, which just removed the self-answer, got rejected. I guess it's fine as it is so I will just leave it as it is, although ChrisHayes' suggestion looks good too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should still edit the answer out of the question.  Answers belong in answers, not in questions.  If the author of the question wants to acknowledge the answer that they found most helpful at solving their problem they can accept it, bringing it to the top.

Comment: I suggested [an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6345738) in which I removed the answer and I added a comment linking to answer, but the edit was rejected. I guess not everyone wanted the answer-part removed. I will leave it to a future visitor who sees it when the new answer is higher up the page.

Comment: @dennisschagt I went ahead and made the edit. If the OP is that keen to have this as the top answer they can accept the answer that already says the same. (For what it's worth if there wasn't already an answer saying the same you can post something, CW if you want, and then the owner of the post can be altered to show that it really was a self-answer via a flag).

Comment: @Flexo Is that reasonable practice if you see a answer-in-question: Cut, paste*, CW and flag? ... *with changes made to ensure it makes sense standalone.

Comment: @dav_i yes, although you can also use comments to ask the OP to do it themselves if they've been active recently and there's a caveat about making a judgement if the answer/question are worth the effort. (I.e. should you vote to close instead?)

Comment: [Bringing to the top does not work for self-answers.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261635/2157640) (Also [in FAQ @ MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238706).)

Comment: @Palec Although the answer being discussed here isn't from the question author, so that's not going to be a problem.

Comment: @Servy I believe meta question create precedents, people will refer to them in the future, in the context of other specific cases. I wanted to point out the corner case.