# Question asking for list of development guidelines

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, community-wiki

There is a one year old question [asking for development and design guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22735174/1730559) which has quite a number of up votes. The original question provided a list of guidelines which the OP had already identified and was asking for further guidelines. Then in the comments to the question further guidelines had been added.

The issues I see are:

- It is border-line off topic as it can't really be answered by a single answer (too broad)
- It contains the answer in the question which should be [moved to an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question)
- Further guidelines are in the comments which may not be seen
- It could be considered a duplicate of other questions: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196606/supporting-dpi-and-default-font-changes) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850915/winforms-different-dpi-layouts) [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296810/how-can-i-make-my-winforms-application-dpi-aware) [(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application) [(5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209905/making-an-existing-net-windows-application-to-be-dpi-aware)

As other users had also asked for the guidelines to be moved to an answer I did just that and edited the question and moved the guidelines into a community wiki answer. The OP has taken issue with this which I guess is fair as he is not the author of the answer even though it is his work. He claims "numerous people complementing this on being a well-written question". I disagree and think that most people would have up voted the question for the list of guidelines.

The question is fairly important as it is currently the first returned result in Google when searching for "[winforms dpi](https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr#q=winforms+dpi)" and "[winforms scale](https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr#q=winforms+scale)". I also think that having a list of things to do and not do is useful and obviously others do too by the up votes. This was the reasoning I had for using a community wiki.

So what should be done?

- Revert the changes and leave a question not fitting the SO standard
- Close it as a duplicate even though it has higher votes than other questions
- Leave my changes and the community wiki

Comment: The comments make it fairly clear: at least five users voted up because the question was good but thought that the answer should be pushed into a separate post. Assuming you're not one of them, that's seven, and that's already a pretty fair fraction. Nobody has disagreed with them, seemingly.