# User editing self-answer and comments in the question itself, wishes to retain "discourse"

Tags: discussion, edits, self-answer

The question itself is [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript?noredirect=1) ; it's a very popular and arguably quite useful question. Since OP used the question itself as a comment board, and posted own solution there, [I tried to defluff the answer so it'd meet the guideline of not having an answer & comments in the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1353684/revisions) The OP responded *[I felt your edit reduced the value of this entry. It may not be a "pure" Q&A format but there was discourse here that was lost.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment63825084_1353684)* What's the correct action I should take in such situations? I've considered the following options:

1. Respect the OP's request over the guidelines, and leave the question be completely.
2. Bring it to Meta, since it should be analysed on per-case basis.
3. Flag it for moderation, since it's an edit dispute.
4. Simply post related meta guidelines and revert the edit again.

Related:

- [Editing self-answer out of question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question)
- [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)
- [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)

Comment: http://www.discourse.org

Comment: I think your edit is correct. If the OP wants to post an answer, they are welcome to do so *as an answer*.

Comment: *"there was discourse here that was lost."* Yeah, that's kind of the point.

Comment: @BoltClock Jeff Atwood is obviously still haunting down the place :p

Comment: Related: *[Is it recommended to notify the answer “Edits” with an heading followed by the edit content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230692/is-it-recommended-to-notify-the-answer-edits-with-an-heading-followed-by-the-e/230693#230693)* and *[When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639)* (cross site).

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks, mate; I've tried on meta.SO, but you're completely right that this has been covered on meta.SE

Comment: Well to begin with, get 8 hours of sleep.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think your edits were appropriate. The various "EDIT" lines add nothing of value. I think the OP was mainly concerned about you removing their answer from the question.

The SO format is pretty clear. Questions should contain questions, answers should contain answers. Period. Community wikis or "canonical duplicates" are no exception. If the OP wish to post the "final function based on x's answer", they should do so as a separate answer.

I propose a rollback to your edit and that we encourage the OP to post the answer part as a separate answer to the question. Preferably a diamond mod should do the final judgement call here, so that we don't end up in some "edit war".

Answer (score 2):

I'm the OP of the question in question.
The [meta topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) linked by @vaxquis refers to a much different situation, in which a question has no answers. In this case the core technical aspect was answered in the accepted answer, but not packaged as my question as aiming for. I felt writing a new answer would be inappropriate instead of recognizing the right answer.

That said I understand the arguments presented here and definitely don't want an edit war. I wanted to start a discussion with @vaxquis regarding the edit. I guess I should have started this meta topic myself instead.

Comment: I've posted [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) only as example of meta about this situation - I've explicitly stated "please see the relevant meta topic**s** to learn the rationale behind [removing fluff, discourse & answers from questions]" (note the plural there) - there are couple of duplicates, covering the whole range of situations (e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question etc.) - if you had only wished to find them, you'd certainly find them.

Comment: BTW, the very fact you "wanted to start a discussion with [me]" by posting a comment under your answer is IMO an indicator of wrong approach - SO basically ain't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. IMO the very first thing you should do after seeing an edit that you'd wish to rollback is to verify the actual site rules concerning the content removed/added by the edit. Frankly, for me this was a completely clear case in the very beginning - otherwise I wouldn't do an edit but would left a comment for you myself; I brought it to meta to avoid conflict escalation, not to prove my point.