# Why is the accepted answer on top?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

I have a somewhat similar question to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261634/why-is-the-accepted-answer-not-on-top). Except that I frequently stumble upon questions with "answers" that are not the best or even bad. ([Take a look at this for one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507948/how-can-i-insert-null-data-into-mysql-database-with-python))

My suggestion is to have a separate order that would put the accepted answer on top and keep ordering by votes strictly in the order of upvotes, possibly pushing the accepted answer to the very bottom.

Comment: You are not the first to observe this problem. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178439/can-we-exempt-downvoted-accepted-answers-from-getting-the-top-spot and a bunch of other prior discussions.