# Why is my own accepted answer not on top?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, sorting

I have a [question which I self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654684/), and my accepted answer is not on top.

I know [that is by design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261634/).

But why? My answer works - I can tell best, because I had the problem. And now all these other answers that are totally wrong stay on top of mine and people looking for an answer probably first try the other solutions until the find the correct answer at the bottom.

Comment: Wisdom of the masses. The thing that SO is predicated on, right? There's a substantial number of people who believe that pinning accepted answers to the top shouldn't happen - that this is an edge case where it indeed doesn't happen is besides that point.

Comment: As you point out, this is by-design. Self-accepted answers don't rise to the top like other accepted answers.  Here's a [post on MSE about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93212/self-answer-accepts-should-dock-at-the-top-like-any-other-post) which then links to the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) which specifically states "No change in sort order. Normally, accepted answers are “docked” under the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers; they stay in standard sort order like any other answer."

Comment: @bluefeet - he's asking for reasoning for that behavior.

Comment: And mostly the reason? Usually the asker of a question is the least qualified to select the best answer (otherwise - why would they be asking). This is the generalization of a natural - "selecting my own answer as the best, because I would know best" which has been formalized in this behavior (that is - most askers who self answer, will many times accept their own answer despite it not being objectively the best).

Comment: @oded: I accept this comment.

Comment: I almost wish I asked the question ;)

Comment: And that's your completely unbiased opinion, absolutely no conflict of interest whatsoever. In fact just to be sure, you asked yourself for a second opinion and what do you know you still thought it was the best answer so that proves it should go first.

Comment: @RobertLongson - when I'm in two minds about something, and get those two minds to agree with each other, I know my thoughts must be right.

Comment: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/839601)

Answer (score 10):

It is somewhat counter-intuitive.

That an asker of a question is usually the least qualified person to select the best answer is generally taken as a given by the community here and is also why we insist that the signal an accept gives is just a "this answer helped me most" by the question OP.

Given this belief, you will find many requests over the years (here and other metas) to not pin the accepted answer to the top when ordering by votes, but actually order by votes.

When it comes to self answers, there is a natural tendency by people to select their own answer as "this helped me best", given it is *their answer to their question*. And given that... well... they are seen as least qualified to select the *best* answer and are likely to not be objective when it comes to their own answer - a natural response is to sort such answers according to community votes only.