# Why are suggested edits not allowed Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, meta

> [image]

I really don't get the purpose of forbidding suggested edits on Meta. Why are they not allowed?

Comment: See [Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890)

Comment: Can we get an updated answer to this question?

Answer (score 7):

### Too Much Work for Moderators (On Small Exchanges)

As pointed out in [Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites/97371#97371) by someone who [now works for The Enemy](http://blog.codinghorror.com/civilized-discourse-construction-kit/),

> Mostly because the per-site metas are generally low traffic -- some of them count daily visits in the *dozens*.
>
> That means the moderators will have to do the work...
>
> We were uncomfortable adding Yet Another Queue for Moderators to Look At across every site in the network.

### Jon Ericson Suggested a Change

Jon Ericson suggested that [suggested Meta edits be made to go into the main site review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171784/163250), to increase participation in Meta,

> Low meta participation is a problem. Since a policy is decided in meta, it can be discouraging to discover that people don't know about meta or simply ignore it...
>
> At any rate, if the only reason for not doing suggested edits is the limited number of people who will be able to review them, why not implement the suggestion made by [Paŭlo Ebermann](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites#comment282752_97371) and [Kevin Vermeer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites#comment283933_97371)?

However, as far as I know, this was never made into a formal feature request, so it hasn't really been discussed all that much.

<sub>Thanks to Martijn for [pointing out the Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262001/why-are-suggested-edits-are-not-allowed-on-per-site-metas/262007#comment50095_262001).</sub>

Comment: Guys, my answer wasn't meant to be a feature request, I was merely pointing out the suggestion that Jon Ericson made.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi this header "Jon Ericson Suggested a Change" originally said "Suggested Change" in my very first revision (you can't see it because it was in the edit grace period), which was not meant as a feature request, but I could see how it could easily be misinterpreted as one. Anyways, that's how I interpreted the downvotes. Tim [specifically says not to worry about cross-site duplication](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251428/456814).

Comment: Indeed, only those who cast them know why. I was about to say leaving a comment would have helped but that dead horse has been beaten enough already.