# Edit option not clickable

Tags: support, suggested-edits, meta

I noticed that here in meta I can't edit posts cause the "link" is not clickable for me, I thought that maybe the post was under an edit review or simply locked by a high rep. But I proceeded to open all the questions and saw that simply that option is not available for me. I'm unaware of policies that would prohibit me from doing so, so any enlightenment on the subject is very much appreciated.

Comment: There are no suggested edits for posts on meta, only tag wikis and excerpts. That was the best reference I could find. If you have 2k, then you can just do it. (couldn't resist, yet again)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I couldn't find it myself. It seems the answer is to earn more rep. @TinyGiant ha! It's funny how you always seem to find ways to use my username haha

Comment: [Found a better dupe, but too late](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262001/why-are-suggested-edits-not-allowed-meta-stack-overflow)