# Can we avoid white-space only edits to make posts get into Reopen votes queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

It seems that white-space only edits ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23888141)) don't make a difference about a post being closed: a duplicate stays duplicate, off-topic doesn't become on-topic, too broad don't get more specific etc. May be, just may be in some special cases they can help with "unclear what you're asking", but that's unlikely and even if it is so, one always has an option to ask for reopening. (this seems to apply to python posts as well)

On the other hand, automatic "reopen suggestions" because of such edits take some efforts from reviewers before they realize that it's quite safe to mark such posts "leave closed".

So I wonder: can we prevent such edits from generating "reopen votes" queue items? Should we?

PS another obvious case: (de)capitalizing letters, doesn't fix the "should be closed" state, too

Comment: It's whitespace + tag, though. I don't know the algorithm, but that might've contributed to it ending up in the reopen queue

Comment: @ErikA nice catch, not sure either

Comment: Related:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388770/817643