# On Meta, the "Update the question" link in the close banner erroneously suggests there's an existing pending edit to users under 2k rep

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, meta, user-experience

The new close banners include a link inviting users to "Update the question" to make it on topic for the site:

[image: Image of the close banner, containing the text "Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers. Want to improve this question? Update the question so it's on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow. Closed 5 hours ago." In the image, "off-topic," "Update the question" and "on-topic" are all links. The "Update the question" link is circled.]

Forgetting for a moment that I was on Meta and don't have enough reputation to make edits here, I saw a question I could improve and clicked that link. I was brought to the edit page which, for users with less than 2k reputation, contains only the message: "*There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.*"

This is obviously false because [suggested edits aren't allowed on normal posts on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262001/7795130), so there couldn't be a pending suggested edit.

Upon further investigation, I believe the bug here isn't what the page is saying, but rather the link to the page being accessible from the question. Before these new post notices, there wasn't a link to `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/POSTID/edit` available to users with less than 2,000 reputation anywhere (The edit button for those users links back to the current page, and instead of navigating, clicking causes an event displaying "*Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites*"). The only way to reach that page was by typing in the URL, so it wasn't reasonably discoverable. Since it wasn't linked to by anything, it wasn't necessary to maintain it or attempt to make it accurate.

I believe the proper fix to this bug would be to make the "Update the question" link behave just like the "edit" button below it: If you have 2k+ rep, it takes you to the edit page, if not, it generates the notice explaining that suggested edits are not allowed.