# Strange, confusing wording on closed questions in Meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, closed-questions, post-notice

I've just realized that in Meta, this part of the wording for improving closed questions is confusing on Meta:

> [image: close post notice]

> Want to improve this question? Add details and clarify the problem by editing this post.

On Meta, if you don't have edit privileges which are available at 2,000 reputation, you cannot suggest an edit to a Meta post.

I would suggest removing this message for people who have <2,000 rep to stop causing confusion.

I've realized that closed questions need editing by the author, so perhaps we could remove this message for everyone except the OP.

---

Related:
If I click the "editing this post" link, then what happens is that it goes to meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/XXXXXX/edit, but instead of notifying that in Meta you can't edit a question if you have <2,000 rep, it says this:

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.

Comment: But the OP can edit their question regardless of reputation.

Comment: I'm talking about other people, not the OP

Comment: I suggest removing this button for everyone, as Questions are usually closed because only the author can fix it.

Comment: I made a request about that banner a few months ago, though your solution encompasses more things and would solve mine too. [On Meta, the “Update the question” link in the close banner erroneously suggests there's an existing pending edit to users under 2k rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396327/on-meta-the-update-the-question-link-in-the-close-banner-erroneously-suggests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should remove that button for everyone except the author.

I don't think I have ever used it. In fact, if the question is closed I try not to edit it because that could push it into the reopen review queue. Some users even go as far as to point it out to you that if you are not the author you should not edit closed posts.

We already have an edit button so we don't need that button. It's just a visual noise for everyone else.

Comment: *"Some users even go as far as to point it out to you that if you are not the author you should not edit closed posts."* Ugh, I hope not. This is totally wrong. Please do edit posts when you can salvage them. That's the whole point of editing. I frequently edit and re-open Meta posts. Before I was a moderator and could single-handedly re-open things, I just edited them and voted to re-open. Others are strongly encouraged to do the same.

Comment: @CodyGray *"Please do edit posts **when** you can salvage them."* The primary reason why we close them is that we can't salvage them ourselves. If an edit could make the question on topic why didn't the people with close vote privilege edit it instead of close voting? But if the question only needs some editing then it's a very good reason to push it into the reopen review queue, which I believe is also done when one votes to reopen it.