# « You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds. » Why?

Tags: support, edits, comments, rate-limiting

In many occasions, the following message appears to me when I want to edit a comment of mine.

> You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.

Let's say I post a comment that contains several unseen typos. I edit the comment to correct one of them but leave another. I then want to quickly re-edit the comment to correct the second typo and I'm provided with the following message when trying to save.

[image]

So I'm wondering what is the reason behind this limitation. Is this to limit the number of ajax request made to the server?

<sup>Sorry if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find the main topic regarding time limitation (as I'm sure there is).</sup>

---

As it appears that this question could be a duplicate of this one: [Why the minimum of 5 seconds between comments votes ?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250174/why-the-minimum-of-5-seconds-between-comment-votes), I would like to state that the answer provided does not fully adress my question because it is mainly focused on voting on comments rather than edits: "*I prefer to base my **voting** not just on my own prior knowledge, but also on what I learn from the combined wisdom of everyone who has already written on the question.*"

Comment: Read more posts with the [meta-tag:rate-limiting] meta tag.  It's probably explained somewhere there.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Thanks for that tag I wasn't aware of but the closest I could find was this question: [Why the minimum of 5 seconds between comments votes ?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250174/why-the-minimum-of-5-seconds-between-comment-votes).

Comment: lol. i tried to click the X on the image in your question twice. that's how normal it is for me to see it.

Comment: @KevinB: Twice? How come, when the first click redirected you to the full size image? :)

Comment: I went to another question and came back :) i'm bad about editing comments way too much.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question is about voting on comments, this one is about editing comments.