# Five-seconds grace for editing not working sometimes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, comments

Sometimes, right after posting a comment on a question or an answer, I want to edit it, and when I immediately (probably in less than a second) try to edit it, it shows that I may only edit a comment every five seconds, and it does not let me edit. I cannot tell under what conditions this happens, but it is quite frequent. I suspect there must be a bug related to this.

Comment: The grace period is five minutes. I have no idea about five seconds. Lemme try clicking edit on mine. Seems to work.

Comment: BoltClock Sorry. It was my mistake. I edited it.

Comment: @sawa I think you mean that you can't edit your comment after 5 seconds right? (*You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds*)

Comment: @Rizier123 Exactly. That was it. And BlotClock, I had the wrong message and the grace was indeed five seconds. I edited the question again.

Comment: @sawa That is bydesign, see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250174/3933332